# Which is faster: Stack allocation or Heap allocation

Tags: c++, performance, memory, stack, heap-memory

This question may sound fairly elementary, but this is a debate I had with another developer I work with.

I was taking care to stack allocate things where I could, instead of heap allocating them. He was talking to me and watching over my shoulder and commented that it wasn't necessary because they are the same performance wise.

I was always under the impression that growing the stack was constant time, and heap allocation's performance depended on the current complexity of the heap for both allocation (finding a hole of the proper size) and de-allocating (collapsing holes to reduce fragmentation, as many standard library implementations take time to do this during deletes if I am not mistaken).

This strikes me as something that would probably be very compiler dependent. For this project in particular I am using a [Metrowerks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrowerks) compiler for the [PPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) architecture. Insight on this combination would be most helpful, but in general, for GCC, and MSVC++, what is the case? Is heap allocation not as high performing as stack allocation? Is there no difference? Or are the differences so minute it becomes pointless micro-optimization.

Comment: why not simply replace empty e; with something like int j=i; that would make sure that stack allocation did take place.

Comment: stack allocation is much faster.

Comment: I know this is pretty ancient, but it'd be nice to see some C/C++ snippets demonstrating the different kinds of allocation.

Comment: Your cow orker is terribly ignorant, but more important he's dangerous because he makes authoritative claims about things he is terribly ignorant about. Excise such people from your team as quickly as possible.

Comment: Note that the heap is usually *much* larger than the stack. If you are allocated large amounts of data, you really have to put it on the heap, or else change the stack size from the OS.

Comment: All optimizations are, unless you have benchmarks or complexity arguments proving otherwise, by default pointless micro-optimizations.

Comment: I wonder if your coworker has mostly Java or C# experience.  In those languages, nearly everything is heap-allocated under the hood, which might lead to such assumptions.

Comment: Relevant (for any language): [How does the stack work in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/556714/264047). When one knows what the stack is it's pretty obvious there is no way heap allocation can be faster.

Comment: There is a famous and old paper by Andrew Appel [*Garbage collection can be faster than stack allocation*](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.pdf)

Answer (score 543, accepted):

Stack allocation is much faster since all it really does is move the stack pointer. 
Using memory pools, you can get comparable performance out of heap allocation, but that comes with a slight added complexity and its own headaches.

Also, stack vs. heap is not only a performance consideration; it also tells you a lot about the expected lifetime of objects.

Comment: And more important, stack is always hot, the memory you get is much more likely to be in cache than any far heap allocated memory

Comment: On some (mostly embedded, that I know of) architectures, stack may be stored in fast on-die memory (e.g. SRAM).  This can make a huge difference!

Comment: @Benoît Could you explain then why not simply store everything on the stack? What's the point of the heap ?

Comment: Because the stack is actually, a stack. You can't free a chunk of memory used by the stack unless it is on top of it. There's no management, you push or pop things on it. On the other hand, the heap memory is managed: it asks the kernel for memory chunks, maybe splits them, merges thems, reuses them and frees them. The stack is really meant for fast and short allocations.

Comment: @Pacerier Because the Stack is a lot smaller than the Heap. If you want to allocate big arrays, you better allocate them on the Heap. If you try to allocate a big array on the Stack it would give you a Stack Overflow. Try for example in C++ this: int t[100000000]; Try for example t[10000000] = 10; and then cout << t[10000000]; It should give you a stack overflow or just won't work and won't show you anything. But if you allocate the array on the heap: int *t = new int[100000000]; and do the same operations after, it will work because the Heap has the necessary size for such a big array.

Comment: @Pacerier The most obvious reason is that objects on the stack go out of scope upon exiting the block they are allocated in.

Comment: @Benoît - Your comment helped me connect a lot of ideas.
The Stack is memory allocated from compiled code; computations are made once and cached during compilation. The Heap is memory allocated during run-time; computations are made as the program runs - computations are not cached before the script is run. Scripting languages (e.g. Javascript), are not compiled, and all memory is allocated to the Heap as the code runs in the browser.
In languages like C++, arrays allocate memory to the Stack from compiled code, and vectors (run-time arrays) allocate memory to the Heap.

Comment: this last comment really confuses me! :/

Comment: @hochl Scripting languages such as Javascript or Python are typically interpreted, which means they're typically turned into machine code line by line. JS and Python still use a stack-heap memory model, so those interpreters have to figure out during execution (run-time) how to store objects (frequently with dynamic size) with a limited stack size. In contrast, compiled languages are able to run through an entire program and save a lot of informations about functions and local variables, along with (dependong on the language) having certain guarantees over whether an object is dynamic or not.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm confused by this answer because doesn't the pointer to the heap get popped off the stack anyway? So it's no different from it being allocated on the stack except that it would cause a stack overflow, which is really the only reason this is not possible.

Comment: @Adam One normally stores the address of a heap-allocated item in some persistent data structure. Note the second sentence of the answer: "stack vs. heap ... tells you a lot about the expected lifetime of objects". Your question indicates that you're very new to C ... I suggest getting more extensive instruction than I can provide here. (And SO comments aren't really intended for this sort of thing.)

Comment: @hochl That's because it is completely and utterly wrong. The stack and the heap are both defined and operated on at runtime. (And the comment from John Cramerus is also nonsensical.)

Comment: @Adam I should add that a pointer to heap allocated memory is often a function's return value. Regardless of whether a pointer to the memory was popped off the stack (more often the pointer occupies a register and is never stored on the stack), the memory continues to be allocated in the heap until it is freed. If it isn't eventually freed then there's a memory leak.

Answer (score 180):

Stack is much faster.  It literally only uses a single instruction on most architectures, in most cases, e.g. on x86:

```
sub esp, 0x10
```

(That moves the stack pointer down by 0x10 bytes and thereby "allocates" those bytes for use by a variable.)

Of course, the stack's size is very, very finite, as you will quickly find out if you overuse stack allocation or try to do recursion :-)

Also, there's little reason to optimize the performance of code that doesn't verifiably need it, such as demonstrated by profiling.  "Premature optimization" often causes more problems than it's worth.

My rule of thumb: if I know I'm going to need some data *at compile-time*, and it's under a few hundred bytes in size, I stack-allocate it.  Otherwise I heap-allocate it.

Comment: One instruction, and that is usually shared by ALL objects on the stack.

Comment: Made the point well, especially the point about verifiably needing it. I'm continually amazed at how people's concerns about performance are misplaced.

Comment: "Deallocation" is also very simple and is done with single `leave` instruction.

Comment: Keep in mind the "hidden" cost here, especially for the first time you extend the stack. Doing so might result in a page fault, a context switch to the kernel which needs to do some work to allocate the memory(or load it from swap, in worst case).

Comment: In some cases, you can even allocate it with 0 instructions.  If some information is known about how many bytes need to be allocated, the compiler can allocate them in advance at the same time it allocates other stack variables.  In those cases, you pay nothing at all!

Comment: @cortammon, I think that's what [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation/161073?noredirect=1#comment54552_161073) meant as well.

Comment: @nos Heap allocations also cause page faults.

Answer (score 127):

Honestly, it's trivial to write a program to compare the performance:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    class empty { }; // even empty classes take up 1 byte of space, minimum
}

int main()
{
    std::clock_t start = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        empty e;
    std::clock_t duration = std::clock() - start;
    std::cout << "stack allocation took " << duration << " clock ticks\n";
    start = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        empty* e = new empty;
        delete e;
    };
    duration = std::clock() - start;
    std::cout << "heap allocation took " << duration << " clock ticks\n";
}
```

It's said that [a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="a+foolish+consistency+is+the+hobgoblin+of+little+minds"&btnG=Search).  Apparently optimizing compilers are the hobgoblins of many programmers' minds.  This discussion used to be at the bottom of the answer, but people apparently can't be bothered to read that far, so I'm moving it up here to avoid getting questions that I've already answered.

**An optimizing compiler may notice that this code does nothing, and may optimize it all away. It is the optimizer's job to do stuff like that, and fighting the optimizer is a fool's errand.**

**I would recommend compiling this code with optimization turned off because there is no good way to fool every optimizer currently in use or that will be in use in the future.**

**Anybody who turns the optimizer on and then complains about fighting it should be subject to public ridicule.**

If I cared about nanosecond precision I wouldn't use `std::clock()`. If I wanted to publish the results as a doctoral thesis I would make a bigger deal about this, and I would probably compare GCC, Tendra/Ten15, LLVM, Watcom, Borland, Visual C++, Digital Mars, ICC and other compilers.  As it is, heap allocation takes hundreds of times longer than stack allocation, and I don't see anything useful about investigating the question any further.

The optimizer has a mission to get rid of the code I'm testing.  I don't see any reason to tell the optimizer to run and then try to fool the optimizer into not actually optimizing.  But if I saw value in doing that, I would do one or more of the following:

1. Add a data member to `empty`, and access that data member in the loop; but if I only ever read from the data member the optimizer can do constant folding and remove the loop; if I only ever write to the data member, the optimizer may skip all but the very last iteration of the loop.  Additionally, the question wasn't "stack allocation and data access vs. heap allocation and data access."
2. Declare `e` `volatile`, [but `volatile` is often compiled incorrectly](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf) (PDF).
3. Take the address of `e` inside the loop (and maybe assign it to a variable that is declared `extern` and defined in another file).  But even in this case, the compiler may notice that -- on the stack at least -- `e` will always be allocated at the same memory address, and then do constant folding like in (1) above.  I get all iterations of the loop, but the object is never actually allocated.

Beyond the obvious, this test is flawed in that it measures both allocation and deallocation, and the original question didn't ask about deallocation.  Of course variables allocated on the stack are automatically deallocated at the end of their scope, so not calling `delete` would (1) skew the numbers (stack deallocation is included in the numbers about stack allocation, so it's only fair to measure heap deallocation) and (2) cause a pretty bad memory leak, unless we keep a reference to the new pointer and call `delete` after we've got our time measurement.

On my machine, using g++ 3.4.4 on Windows, I get "0 clock ticks" for both stack and heap allocation for anything less than 100000 allocations, and even then I get "0 clock ticks" for stack allocation and "15 clock ticks" for heap allocation.  When I measure 10,000,000 allocations, stack allocation takes 31 clock ticks and heap allocation takes 1562 clock ticks.

---

Yes, an optimizing compiler may elide creating the empty objects.  If I understand correctly, it may even elide the whole first loop.  When I bumped up the iterations to 10,000,000 stack allocation took 31 clock ticks and heap allocation took 1562 clock ticks.  I think it's safe to say that without telling g++ to optimize the executable, g++ did not elide the constructors.

---

In the years since I wrote this, the preference on Stack Overflow has been to post performance from optimized builds.  In general, I think this is correct.  However, I still think it's silly to ask the compiler to optimize code when you in fact do not want that code optimized.  It strikes me as being very similar to paying extra for valet parking, but refusing to hand over the keys.  In this particular case, I don't want the optimizer running.

Using a slightly modified version of the benchmark (to address the valid point that the original program didn't allocate something on the stack each time through the loop) and compiling without optimizations but linking to release libraries (to address the valid point that we don't want to include any slowdown caused by linking to debug libraries):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

namespace {
    void on_stack()
    {
        int i;
    }

    void on_heap()
    {
        int* i = new int;
        delete i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        on_stack();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::printf("on_stack took %f seconds\n", std::chrono::duration<double>(end - begin).count());

    begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        on_heap();
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::printf("on_heap took %f seconds\n", std::chrono::duration<double>(end - begin).count());
    return 0;
}
```

displays:

```
on_stack took 2.070003 seconds
on_heap took 57.980081 seconds
```

on my system when compiled with the command line `cl foo.cc /Od /MT /EHsc`.

You may not agree with my approach to getting a non-optimized build.  That's fine:  feel free modify the benchmark as much as you want.  When I turn on optimization, I get:

```
on_stack took 0.000000 seconds
on_heap took 51.608723 seconds
```

Not because stack allocation is actually instantaneous but because any half-decent compiler can notice that `on_stack` doesn't do anything useful and can be optimized away.  GCC on my Linux laptop also notices that `on_heap` doesn't do anything useful, and optimizes it away as well:

```
on_stack took 0.000003 seconds
on_heap took 0.000002 seconds
```

Comment: Your example is flawed: any decent compiler is going to take out the "empty e" line from the 3rd line (main sub) in the common sub-expression elimination and dead-code elimination phases. Better do that within a function and call it from the loop. Probably you should do the same for stack.

Comment: Also, you should add a "calibration" loop at the very beginning of your main function, something to give you an idea how much time per loop-cycle you're getting, and adjust the other loops so as to ensure your example runs for some amount of time, instead of the fixed constant you're using.

Comment: Calibration loop: if it runs for too short, your results won't be statistically significant. When you moved it to 10 million, you got significant results. However, on my old 386 the original 100K would have been more than adequate for the task, hence the need for the calibration loop.

Comment: I'm also glad increasing the number of times each option loop runs (plus instructing g++ not to optimize?) has yielded significant results. So now we have hard facts to say stack is faster. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: What you are claiming is *wrong*. The compiler won't emit any code to grow the stack for your empty class. I compiled your source without optimization under VS 2005 and disassembled the exe with IDA - no stack allocation at all.

Comment: What I am claiming is (1) a test program is trivial, and (2) GCC has these performance characteristics. The C++ standard requires that objects take up at least one byte of space; if Microsoft isn't following the standard I'm sure you can figure out how to make the object take up space.

Comment: The answer also said "To be on the safe side, it would be possible to add a field to empty ... and access that field. ... Taking the address of e would also work, and 'should' take the same amount of time in both loops." I find it odd you disassembled an exe but didn't read the whole answer.

Comment: Well it's the same for GCC at least with optimization turned on - no stack allocation even with additional fields

Comment: That's why I turned optimization off.  I'm not trying to find the best timing results ever.  I'm not going to publish the results as part of a doctoral thesis.  I simply wanted to demonstrate that malloc is hundreds of times slower than stack allocation.

Comment: It's the optimizer's job to get rid of code like this. Is there a good reason to turn the optimizer on and then prevent it from actually optimizing? I've edited the answer to make things even clearer: if you enjoy fighting the optimizer, be prepared to learn how smart compiler writers are.

Comment: You are only allocating the object on the stack once. To allocate 10000 objects, you need to do empty array[10000];

Comment: I'm very late, but it is also very worth mentioning here that heap allocation requests memory through the kernel, so the performance hit also strongly depends on the efficiency of the kernel.  Using this code with Linux (Linux 3.10.7-gentoo #2 SMP Wed Sep 4 18:58:21 MDT 2013 x86_64), modifying for the HR timer, and using 100 million iterations in each loop yields this performance: `stack allocation took 0.15354 seconds, heap allocation took 0.834044 seconds` with `-O0` set, making Linux heap allocation only slower on a factor of about 5.5 on my particular machine.

Comment: On windows without optimizations (debug build) it will use the debug heap which is much slower than the non debug heap. I don't think its a bad idea to "trick" the optimizer at all. Compiler writers are smart, but compilers are not AI's.

Comment: @paulm: Looking at the options for `cl.exe` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx ), I believe it is possible to disable optimizations (`/Od`) while linking with the release runtime (`/MT`).

Comment: If you change on_stack() to have 100 vars, its time would be the same.  But making the same change to on_heap() will make it 100 times slower.

Comment: @brianbeuning:  that is a good point.  Perhaps I should have called `alloca` 100 times.

Comment: Microbenchmarking is hard.  You can't just disable optimization, because that gives you unrealistic code-gen: e.g. keeping the loop counter in memory so you bottleneck on 1 iteration per ~6 clock cycles, from store-forwarding latency.  You definitely want the optimizer to optimize everything you aren't measuring, and force it to do the work you actually want to measure.  e.g. put your target function in a separate file and disable link-time optimization, or use `[noinline]` on the functions.  You may need `volatile`.  You usually have to check the asm to make sure you got what you wanted.

Comment: See [C loop optimization help for final assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001196) for more about why debug builds `gcc -O0` are ridiculous.   It's not even close to a linear slowdown that affects all code equally.  See [Adding a redundant assignment speeds up code when compiled without optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49189685) for a case where it leads to super-weird results because of store-forwarding latency quirks on Sandybridge-family.

Answer (score 34):

An interesting thing I learned about Stack vs. Heap Allocation on the Xbox 360 Xenon processor, which may also apply to other multicore systems, is that allocating on the Heap causes a Critical Section to be entered to halt all other cores so that the alloc doesn't conflict.  Thus, in a tight loop, Stack Allocation was the way to go for fixed sized arrays as it prevented stalls.

This may be another speedup to consider if you're coding for multicore/multiproc, in that your stack allocation will only be viewable by the core running your scoped function, and that will not affect any other cores/CPUs.

Comment: That's true of most multicore machines, not just the Xenon. Even Cell has to do it because you might be running two hardware threads on that PPU core.

Comment: That's an effect of the (particularly poor) implementation of the heap allocator.  Better heap allocators need not acquire a lock on every allocation.

Answer (score 20):

You can write a special heap allocator for specific sizes of objects that is very performant. However, the *general* heap allocator is not particularly performant.

Also I agree with Torbjörn Gyllebring about the expected lifetime of objects. Good point!

Comment: That's sometimes referred as slab allocation.

Answer (score 15):

### Concerns Specific to the C++ Language

First of all, **there is no so-called "stack" or "heap" allocation mandated by C++**. If you are talking about automatic objects in block scopes, they are even not "allocated". (BTW, automatic storage duration in C is definitely NOT the same to "allocated"; the latter is "dynamic" in the C++ parlance.) The dynamically allocated memory is on the *free store*, not necessarily on "the heap", though the latter is often the (default) *implementation*.

Although as per the [abstract machine](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract) semantic rules, automatic objects still occupy memory, a conforming C++ implementation is allowed to ignore this fact when it can prove this does not matter (when it does not change the observable behavior of the program). This permission is granted by [the as-if rule](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#footnote-4) in ISO C++, which is also the general clause enabling the usual optimizations (and there is also an almost same rule in ISO C). Besides the as-if rule, ISO C++ also has [copy elision rules](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision) to allow omission of specific creations of objects. The constructor and destructor calls involved are thereby omitted. As a result, the automatic objects (if any) in these constructors and destructors are also eliminated, compared to naive abstract semantics implied by the source code.

On the other hand, free store allocation is definitely "allocation" by design. Under ISO C++ rules, such an allocation can be achieved by a call of an *allocation function*. However, since ISO C++14, there is [a new (non-as-if) rule](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#12) to allow merging global allocation function (i.e. `::operator new`) calls in specific cases. So parts of dynamic allocation operations can also be no-op like the case of automatic objects.

Allocation functions allocate resources of memory. Objects can be further allocated based on allocation using allocators. For automatic objects, they are directly presented - although the underlying memory can be accessed and be used to provide memory to other objects (by placement `new`), but this does not make great sense as the free store, because there is no way to move the resources elsewhere.

All other concerns are out of the scope of C++. Nevertheless, they can be still significant.

### About Implementations of C++

C++ does not expose reified activation records or some sorts of first-class continuations (e.g. by the famous [`call/cc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call/cc)), there is no way to directly manipulate the activation record frames - where the implementation need to place the automatic objects to. Once there is no (non-portable) interoperations with the underlying implementation ("native" non-portable code, such as inline assembly code), an omission of the underlying allocation of the frames can be quite trivial. For example, when the called function is inlined, the frames can be effectively merged into others, so there is no way to show what is the "allocation".

However, once interops are respected, things are getting complex. A typical implementation of C++ will expose the ability of interop on ISA (instruction-set architecture) with some *calling conventions* as the binary boundary shared with the native (ISA-level machine) code. This would be explicitly costly, notably, when maintaining the *stack pointer*, which is often directly held by an ISA-level register (with probably specific machine instructions to access). The stack pointer indicates the boundary of the top frame of the (currently active) function call. When a function call is entered, a new frame is needed and the stack pointer is added or subtracted (depending on the convention of ISA) by a value not less than the required frame size. The frame is then said **allocated** when the stack pointer after the operations. Parameters of functions may be passed onto the stack frame as well, depending on the calling convention used for the call. The frame can hold the memory of automatic objects (probably including the parameters) specified by the C++ source code. In the sense of such implementations, these objects are "allocated". When the control exits the function call, the frame is no longer needed, it is usually released by restoring the stack pointer back to the state before the call (saved previously according to the calling convention). This can be viewed as "deallocation". These operations make the activation record effectively a LIFO data structure, so it is often called "[the (call) stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)". The stack pointer effectively indicates the top position of the stack.

Because most C++ implementations (particularly the ones targeting ISA-level native code and using the assembly language as its immediate output) use similar strategies like this, such a confusing "allocation" scheme is popular. Such allocations (as well as deallocations) do spend machine cycles, and it can be expensive when the (non-optimized) calls occur frequently, even though modern CPU microarchitectures can have complex optimizations implemented by hardware for the common code pattern (like using a *stack engine* in implementing  `PUSH`/`POP` instructions).

But anyway, in general, **it is true that the cost of stack frame allocation is significantly less than a call to an allocation function operating the free store (unless it is totally optimized away)**, which itself can have hundreds of (if not millions of :-) operations to maintain the stack pointer and other states. Allocation functions are typically based on API provided by the hosted environment (e.g. runtime provided by the OS). Different to the purpose of holding automatic objects for functions calls, such allocations are general-purpose, so they will not have frame structure like a stack. Traditionally, they allocate space from the pool storage called the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP) (or several heaps). Different from the "stack", the concept "heap" here does not indicate the data structure being used; [it is derived from early language implementations decades ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap). (BTW, the call stack is usually allocated with fixed or user-specified size from the heap by the environment in program/thread startup.) The nature of use cases makes allocations and deallocations from a heap far more complicated (than pushing/poppoing of stack frames), and hardly possible to be directly optimized by hardware.

### Effects on Memory Access

The usual stack allocation always puts the new frame on the top, so it has a quite good locality. This is friendly to the cache. OTOH, memory allocated randomly in the free store has no such property. Since ISO C++17, there are pool resource templates provided by `<memory_resource>`. The direct purpose of such an interface is to allow the results of consecutive allocations being close together in memory. This acknowledges the fact that this strategy is generally good for performance with contemporary implementations, e.g. being friendly to cache in modern architectures. This is about the performance of *access* rather than *allocation*, though.

### Concurrency

Expectation of concurrent access to memory can have different effects between the stack and heaps. A call stack is usually exclusively owned by one thread of execution in a typical C++ implementation. OTOH, heaps are often *shared* among the threads in a process. For such heaps, the allocation and deallocation functions have to protect the shared internal administrative data structure from the data race. As a result, heap allocations and deallocations may have additional overhead due to internal synchronization operations.

### Space Efficiency

Due to the nature of the use cases and internal data structures, heaps may suffer from internal [memory fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)), while the stack does not. This does not have direct impacts on the performance of memory allocation, but in a system with [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), low space efficiency may degenerate overall performance of memory access. This is particularly awful when HDD is used as a swap of physical memory. It can cause quite long latency - sometimes billions of cycles.

### Limitations of Stack Allocations

Although stack allocations are often superior in performance than heap allocations in reality, it certainly does not mean stack allocations can always replace heap allocations.

First, there is no way to allocate space on the stack with a size specified at runtime in a portable way with ISO C++. There are extensions provided by implementations like `alloca` and G++'s VLA (variable-length array), but there are reasons to avoid them. (IIRC, Linux source removes the use of VLA recently.) (Also note ISO C99 does have mandated VLA, but ISO C11 turns the support optional.)

Second, there is no reliable and portable way to detect stack space exhaustion. This is often called stack overflow <sub>(hmm, the etymology of this site)</sub>, but probably more accurately, *stack overrun*. In reality, this often causes invalid memory access, and the state of the program is then corrupted (... or maybe worse, a security hole). In fact, ISO C++ has no concept of "the stack" and [makes it undefined behavior when the resource is exhausted](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/xphK7zA65nU/y9_KM4fPAgAJ). Be cautious about how much room should be left for automatic objects.

If the stack space runs out, there are too many objects allocated in the stack, which can be caused by too many active calls of functions or improper use of automatic objects. Such cases may suggest the existence of bugs, e.g. a recursive function call without correct exit conditions.

Nevertheless, deep recursive calls are sometimes desired. In implementations of languages requiring support of unbound active calls (where the call depth only limited by total memory), it is *impossible* to use the (contemporary) native call stack directly as the target language activation record like typical C++ implementations. To work around the problem, alternative ways of the construction of activation records are needed. For example, [SML/NJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML_of_New_Jersey) explicitly allocates frames on the heap and uses [cactus stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_pointer_tree). The complicated allocation of such activation record frames is usually not as fast as the call stack frames. However, if such languages are implemented further with the guarantee of [proper tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), the direct stack allocation in the object language (that is, the "object" in the language does not stored as references, but native primitive values which can be one-to-one mapped to unshared C++ objects) is even more complicated with more performance penalty in general. When using C++ to implement such languages, it is difficult to estimate the performance impacts.

Comment: Like stl, fewer and fewer are willing to diff these concepts. Many dudes on cppcon2018 also use `heap` frequently.

Comment: @陳力 "The heap" can be unambiguous with some specific implementations kept in mind, so it maybe OK sometimes. It is redundant "in general", though.

Comment: What is interop?

Comment: @陳力 I meant any kinds of "native" code interoperations involved in the C++ source, for example, any inline assembly code. This relies on assumptions (of ABI) not covered by C++. COM interop (based on some Windows-specific ABI) is more or less similar, although it is mostly neutral to C++.

Comment: This answer should be scored much higher than it is.  Indeed, [there is no stack](https://miro.medium.com/max/640/0*9Wll0yjE36YG3vl0.jpg).

Comment: One fairly large miswording in the first paragraph.  Dynamic allocations come from the "free store" and deallocations return memory to the "free store" but no allocated object is ever "on" the free store.  The "free store" is the subset of dynamic storage (typically heap) which isn't currently allocated out.  Besides which, the C++ standard only says "dynamic storage", so even mentioning "free store" is just adding to complexity.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's technically incorrect. [Free store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_store) *is* the whole region of the memory for all dynamic allocations. The word "free" refers to the fact of detaching from activation records, rather than the status of being allocated or not.

Comment: @BenVoigt Also note "free store" has been lived for decades in the normative text in ISO C++ until [a recent change](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/7987ef93488842bbdbbd6e4de996f463939fe0e8), so at least the current published standard still clearly mandates it. And this term is still in the [index](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#F) in the draft standard. OTOH, there is no single term *dynamic storage* (besides the class of storage duration) defined by the standard.

Comment: @FrankHB: That was just a section heading being changed.  What was the actual text talking about "free store"?  In fact there is none, never has been (at least back to C++03).

Comment: @FrankHB: Whereas "dynamic storage" is actually a thing, not just a duration.  "A C++ implementation provides access to, and management of, dynamic storage".  Yes, it's related to the dynamic storage duration, but that sentence would make no sense if the word "duration" were inserted.  It would make sense if the term "free store" were substituted... but "free store" is not the verbiage that C++ uses.  "dynamic storage" is.

Comment: @BenVoigt Free store is just a traditional computer science thing, a more high-level abstraction of "the global heap". Bjarne Stroustrup used to use this meaning for a long time (e.g. in [A History of C++](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269031890_A_history_of_C)); consult him if you have any further doubt. Whether it is sufficiently standardized in ISO C++ is another question which does not alter the original intention. About "dynamic storage", if you feel it should be defined normatively, ask WG21 or [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/).

Answer (score 9):

I don't think stack allocation and heap allocation are generally interchangable. I also hope that the performance of both of them is sufficient for general use.

I'd strongly recommend for small items, whichever one is more suitable to the scope of the allocation. For large items, the heap is probably necessary.

On 32-bit operating systems that have multiple threads, stack is often rather limited (albeit typically to at least a few mb), because the address space needs to be carved up and sooner or later one thread stack will run into another. On single threaded systems (Linux glibc single threaded anyway) the limitation is much less because the stack can just grow and grow.

On 64-bit operating systems there is enough address space to make thread stacks quite large.

Answer (score 8):

Usually stack allocation just consists of subtracting from the stack pointer register.  This is tons faster than searching a heap.

Sometimes stack allocation requires adding a page(s) of virtual memory.  Adding a new page of zeroed memory doesn't require reading a page from disk, so usually this is still going to be tons faster than searching a heap (especially if part of the heap was paged out too).  In a rare situation, and you could construct such an example, enough space just happens to be available in part of the heap which is already in RAM, but allocating a new page for the stack has to wait for some other page to get written out to disk.  In that rare situation, the heap is faster.

Comment: I don't think the heap is "searched" unless it's paged. Pretty sure solid state memory uses a multiplexor and can gain direct access to the memory, hence the Random Access Memory.

Comment: Here's an example.  The calling program asks to allocate 37 bytes.  The library function looks for a block of at least 40 bytes.  The first block on the free list has 16 bytes.  The second block on the free list has 12 bytes.  The third block has 44 bytes.  The library stops searching at that point.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the orders-of-magnitude performance advantage over heap allocation, stack allocation is preferable for long running server applications.  Even the best managed heaps eventually get so fragmented that application performance degrades.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the biggest problem of heap allocation versus stack allocation, is that heap allocation in the general case is an unbounded operation, and thus you can't use it where timing is an issue.

For other applications where timing isn't an issue, it may not matter as much, but if you heap allocate a lot, this will affect the execution speed. Always try to use the stack for short lived and often allocated memory (for instance in loops), and as long as possible - do heap allocation during application startup.

Answer (score 5):

A stack has a limited capacity, while a heap is not. The typical stack for a process or thread is around 8K. You cannot change the size once it's allocated.

A stack variable follows the scoping rules, while a heap one doesn't. If your instruction pointer goes beyond a function, all the new variables associated with the function go away.

Most important of all, you can't predict the overall function call chain in advance. So a mere 200 bytes allocation on your part may raise a stack overflow. This is especially important if you're writing a library, not an application.

Comment: The amount of virtual address space allocated for a user mode stack on a modern OS is likely to be at least 64kB or larger by default (1MB on Windows). Are you talking about kernel stack sizes?

Comment: On my machine, the default stack size for a process is 8MB, not kB. How old is your computer?

Answer (score 5):

It's not jsut stack allocation that's faster. You also win a lot on using stack variables. They have better locality of reference. And finally, deallocation is a lot cheaper too.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, stack allocation is generally much faster.

However, if your objects are expensive to copy, allocating on the stack may lead to an huge performance hit later when you use the objects if you aren't careful.

For example, if you allocate something on the stack, and then put it into a container, it would have been better to allocate on the heap and store the pointer in the container (e.g. with a std::shared_ptr<>). The same thing is true if you are passing or returning objects by value, and other similar scenarios.

The point is that although stack allocation is usually better than heap allocation in many cases, sometimes if you go out of your way to stack allocate when it doesn't best fit the model of computation, it can cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 4):

Stack allocation is a couple instructions whereas the fastest rtos heap allocator known to me (TLSF) uses on average on the order of 150 instructions. Also stack allocations don't require a lock because they use thread local storage which is another huge performance win. So stack allocations can be 2-3 orders of magnitude faster depending on how heavily multithreaded your environment is.

In general heap allocation is your last resort if you care about performance. A viable in-between option can be a fixed pool allocator which is also only a couple instructions and has very little per-allocation overhead so it's great for small fixed size objects. On the downside it only works with fixed size objects, is not inherently thread safe and has block fragmentation problems.

Answer (score 3):

I think the lifetime is crucial, and whether the thing being allocated has to be constructed in a complex way.  For example, in transaction-driven modeling, you usually have to fill in and pass in a transaction structure with a bunch of fields to operation functions.  Look at the OSCI SystemC TLM-2.0 standard for an example.

Allocating these on the stack close to the call to the operation tends to cause enormous overhead, as the construction is expensive.  The good way there is to allocate on the heap and reuse the transaction objects either by pooling or a simple policy like "this module only needs one transaction object ever".

This is many times faster than allocating the object on each operation call.

The reason is simply that the object has an expensive construction and a fairly long useful lifetime.

I would say: try both and see what works best in your case, because it can really depend on the behavior of your code.

Answer (score 2):

There's a general point to be made about such optimizations.

**The optimization you get is proportional to the amount of time the program counter is actually in that code.**

If you sample the program counter, you will find out where it spends its time, and that is usually in a tiny part of the code, and often in library routines you have no control over.

Only if you find it spending much time in the heap-allocation of your objects will it be noticeably faster to stack-allocate them.

Answer (score 2):

Stack allocation will almost always be as fast or faster than heap allocation, although it is certainly possible for a heap allocator to simply use a stack based allocation technique.

However, there are larger issues when dealing with the overall performance of stack vs. heap based allocation (or in slightly better terms, local vs. external allocation). Usually, heap (external) allocation is slow because it is dealing with many different kinds of allocations and allocation patterns. Reducing the scope of the allocator you are using (making it local to the algorithm/code) will tend to increase performance without any major changes. Adding better structure to your allocation patterns, for example, forcing a LIFO ordering on allocation and deallocation pairs can also improve your allocator's performance by using the allocator in a simpler and more structured way. Or, you can use or write an allocator tuned for your particular allocation pattern; most programs allocate a few discrete sizes frequently, so a heap that is based on a lookaside buffer of a few fixed (preferably known) sizes will perform extremely well. Windows uses its low-fragmentation-heap for this very reason.

On the other hand, stack-based allocation on a 32-bit memory range is also fraught with peril if you have too many threads. Stacks need a contiguous memory range, so the more threads you have, the more virtual address space you will need for them to run without a stack overflow. This won't be a problem (for now) with 64-bit, but it can certainly wreak havoc in long running programs with lots of threads. Running out of virtual address space due to fragmentation is always a pain to deal with.

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Remark that the considerations are typically not about speed and performance when choosing stack versus heap allocation. The stack acts like a stack, which means it is well suited for pushing blocks and popping them again, last in, first out. Execution of procedures is also stack-like, last procedure entered is first to be exited. In most programming languages, all the variables needed in a procedure will only be visible during the procedure's execution, thus they are pushed upon entering a procedure and popped off the stack upon exit or return.

Now for an example where the stack cannot be used:

```
Proc P
{
  pointer x;
  Proc S
  {
    pointer y;
    y = allocate_some_data();
    x = y;
  }
}
```

If you allocate some memory in procedure S and put it on the stack and then exit S, the allocated data will be popped off the stack. But the variable x in P also pointed to that data, so x is now pointing to some place underneath the stack pointer (assume stack grows downwards) with an unknown content. The content might still be there if the stack pointer is just moved up without clearing the data beneath it, but if you start allocating new data on the stack, the pointer x might actually point to that new data instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) {

    }
}
int func() {
    int a1, a2;
    std::cin >> a1;
    std::cin >> a2;

    Foo f1(a1);
    __asm push a1;
    __asm lea ecx, [this];
    __asm call Foo::Foo(int);

    Foo* f2 = new Foo(a2);
    __asm push sizeof(Foo);
    __asm call operator new;//there's a lot instruction here(depends on system)
    __asm push a2;
    __asm call Foo::Foo(int);

    delete f2;
}
```

It would be like this in asm. When you're in `func`, the `f1` and pointer `f2` has been allocated on stack (automated storage). And by the way, Foo `f1(a1)` has no instruction effects on stack pointer (`esp`),It has been allocated, if `func` wants get the member `f1`, it's instruction is something like this: `lea ecx [ebp+f1], call Foo::SomeFunc()`. Another thing the stack allocate may make someone think the memory is something like `FIFO`, the `FIFO` just happened when you go into some function, if you are in the function and allocate something like `int i = 0`, there no push happened.

Answer (score 1):

It has been mentioned before that stack allocation is simply moving the stack pointer, that is, a single instruction on most architectures. Compare that to what *generally* happens in the case of heap allocation.

The operating system maintains portions of free memory as a linked list with the payload data consisting of the pointer to the starting address of the free portion and the size of the free portion. To allocate X bytes of memory, the link list is traversed and each note is visited in sequence, checking to see if its size is at least X. When a portion with size P >= X is found, P is split into two parts with sizes X and P-X. The linked list is updated and the pointer to the first part is returned.

As you can see, heap allocation depends on may factors like how much memory you are requesting, how fragmented the memory is and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In general, stack allocation is faster than heap allocation as mentioned by almost every answer above.  A stack push or pop is O(1), whereas allocating or freeing from a heap could require a walk of previous allocations.  However you shouldn't usually be allocating in tight, performance-intensive loops, so the choice will usually come down to other factors.

It might be good to make this distinction: you can use a "stack allocator" on the heap.  Strictly speaking, I take stack allocation to mean the actual method of allocation rather than the location of the allocation.  If you're allocating a lot of stuff on the actual program stack, that could be bad for a variety of reasons.  On the other hand, using a stack method to allocate on the heap when possible is the best choice you can make for an allocation method.

Since you mentioned Metrowerks and PPC, I'm guessing you mean Wii.  In this case memory is at a premium, and using a stack allocation method wherever possible guarantees that you don't waste memory on fragments.  Of course, doing this requires a lot more care than "normal" heap allocation methods.  It's wise to evaluate the tradeoffs for each situation.

Answer (score 0):

Never do premature assumption as other application code and usage can impact your function. So looking at function is isolation is of no use.

If you are serious with application then VTune it or use any similar profiling tool and look at hotspots.

Ketan

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, stack allocation is faster. With heap allocation, the allocator has to find the free memory somewhere. With stack allocation, the compiler does it for you by simply giving your function a larger stack frame, which means the allocation costs no time at all. (I'm assuming you're not using `alloca` or anything to allocate a dynamic amount of stack space, but even then it's very fast.)

However, you do have to be wary of hidden dynamic allocation. For example:

```
void some_func()
{
    std::vector<int> my_vector(0x1000);
    // Do stuff with the vector...
}
```

You might think this allocates 4 KiB on the stack, but you'd be wrong. It allocates the `vector` instance on the stack, but that `vector` instance in turn allocates its 4 KiB on the heap, because `vector` *always* allocates its internal array on the heap (at least unless you specify a custom allocator, which I won't get into here). If you want to allocate on the stack using an STL-like container, you probably want [`std::array`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/), or possibly [`boost::static_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html) (provided by the external [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) library).

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to say actually code generate by GCC (I remember VS also) **doesn't have overhead to do stack allocation**.

Say for following function:

```
  int f(int i)
  {
      if (i > 0)
      {   
          int array[1000];
      }   
  }
```

Following is the code generate:

```
  __Z1fi:
  Leh_func_begin1:
      pushq   %rbp
  Ltmp0:
      movq    %rsp, %rbp
  Ltmp1:
      subq    $**3880**, %rsp <--- here we have the array allocated, even the if doesn't excited.
  Ltmp2:
      movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
      movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
      addq    $3880, %rsp
      popq    %rbp
      ret 
  Leh_func_end1:
```

So whatevery how much local variable you have (even inside if or switch), just the 3880 will change to another value. Unless you didn't have local variable, this instruction just need to execute. So allocate local variable doesn't have overhead.

Comment: Generally true. You don't pay for extra instructions if you use more stack space (different from heap allocations). However, you may cause paging from RAM to occur if your stack gets large, slowing things down _a lot_ because disk access is orders of magnitude slower than RAM. Also, in C++, constructors still need to be called, and those are probably the thing that is much slower than the actual memory allocation.