# How does the stack work in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, stack, callstack, stack-memory

I'm currently trying to understand how the stack works, so I've decided teach myself some [assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), I'm using this book:

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/

I'm using [Gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler) and doing my development on [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint).

I'm a bit confused by something:

As far as I was aware a stack is simply a data structure. So I assumed if I was coding in assembly I'd have to implement the stack myself. However this doesn't seem to be the case as there are commands like

```
pushl
popl
```

So when coding in assembly for the [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) architecture and using the Gas syntax: is the stack just a data structure that's already implemented? Or is it actually implemented at the hardware level? Or is it something else? Also would most assembly languages for other chip sets have the stack already implemented?

I know this is a bit of a foolish question but I'm actually quite confused by this.

Comment: Most of these answers talk about the stack as it is used by languages, in particular they talk about passing arguments on the stack.  In many CPUs this is just to make implementing languages easier--If you were hand-coding assembly you'd generally pass parameters to functions in registers (At least before the CPU was optimized for stack operations because the languages used it so heavily).  The stack is mostly to keep calls/returns in order, also an interrupt (which needs to save the state of the CPU) would push existing values in registers it will use and pop them before returning.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I think primarily you're getting confused between a `program's stack` and `any old stack`.

**A Stack**

Is an abstract data structure which consists of information in a Last In First Out system. You put arbitrary objects onto the stack and then you take them off again, much like an in/out tray, the top item is always the one that is taken off and you always put on to the top.

**A Programs Stack**

Is a stack, it's a section of memory that is used during execution, it generally has a static size per program and frequently used to store function parameters. You push the parameters onto the stack when you call a function and the function either address the stack directly or pops off the variables from the stack.

A programs stack isn't generally hardware (though it's kept in memory so it can be argued as such), but the Stack Pointer which points to a current area of the Stack is generally a CPU register. This makes it a bit more flexible than a LIFO stack as you can change the point at which the stack is addressing.

You should read and make sure you understand the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)) article as it gives a good description of the Hardware Stack which is what you are dealing with.

There is also [this tutorial](http://ee.sharif.edu/~sakhtar3/articles/8086/ASM%20Tutorial-Ready%20to%20Start!.htm#stack) which explains the stack in terms of the old 16bit registers but could be helpful and [another one](https://web.archive.org/web/20070822075422/http://www.emu8086.com/assembly_language_tutorial_assembler_reference/asm_tutorial_09.html) specifically about the stack.

From Nils Pipenbrinck:

It's worthy of note that some processors do not implement all of the instructions for accessing and manipulating the stack (push, pop, stack pointer, etc) but the x86 does because of it's frequency of use. In these situations if you wanted a stack you would have to implement it yourself (some MIPS and some ARM processors are created without stacks).

For example, in MIPs a push instruction would be implemented like:

```
addi $sp, $sp, -4  # Decrement stack pointer by 4  
sw   $t0, ($sp)   # Save $t0 to stack
```

and a Pop instruction would look like:

```
lw   $t0, ($sp)   # Copy from stack to $t0  
addi $sp, $sp, 4   # Increment stack pointer by 4
```

Comment: Btw - the x86 has these special stack instructions because pushing and popping stuff from the stack happends so often that it was a good idea to use a short opcode for them (less code-space). Architectures such as MIPS and ARM don't have these, so you have to implement the stack on your own.

Comment: Bear in mind that your hot new processor is binary-compatible with the 8086 to some extent, and that was source-compatible with the 8080, a development of the 8008, the first microprocessor.  Some of these decisions go back a long way.

Comment: In ARM, there are single instructions for manipulating the stack, they are just not so obvious because they are called STMDB SP! (for PUSH) and LDMIA SP! (for POP).

Comment: Some architectures (like TI's C64x, IIRC) don't have special stack instructions, but provide post-/pre- increment/decrement addressing modes, with which any register could be used as a stack pointer (A13, by convention, I think)

Comment: My god this answer is in need of +500... I haven't found anything explained this well since forever. Considering to make new accounts to +1 this as of now...

Comment: @bplus You can also refer to https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html

Answer (score 72):

(I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/amalahov/7c8df89e2dfee956fd2577073981a22d?ts=4) of all the code in this answer in case you want to play with it)

I have only ever did most basic things in asm during my CS101 course back in 2003. And I had never really "got it" how asm and stack work
until I've realized that it's all basicaly like programming in C or C++ ... but without local variables, parameters and functions.
Probably doesn't sound easy yet :) Let me show you (for x86 asm with [Intel syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax)).

---

**1. What is the stack**

Stack is usually a contiguous chunk of memory allocated for every thread before they start. You can store there whatever you want. In C++ terms (*code snippet #1*):

```cpp
const int STACK_CAPACITY = 1000;
thread_local int stack[STACK_CAPACITY];
```

---

**2. Stack's top and bottom**

In principle, you could store values in random cells of `stack` array (*snippet #2.1*):

```cpp
stack[333] = 123;
stack[517] = 456;
stack[555] = stack[333] + stack[517];
```

But imagine how hard would it be to remember which cells of `stack` are already in use and wich ones are "free". That's why we store new values on the stack next to each other.

One weird thing about (x86) asm's stack is that you add things there starting with the last index and move to lower indexes: stack[999], then stack[998] and so on (*snippet #2.2*):

```cpp
stack[999] = 123;
stack[998] = 456;
stack[997] = stack[999] + stack[998];
```

And still (caution, you're gonna be confused now) the "official" name for `stack[999]` is **bottom of the stack**.
The last used cell (`stack[997]` in the example above) is called **top of the stack** (see [Where the top of the stack is on x86](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/)).

---

**3. Stack pointer (SP)**

For the purpose of this discussion let's assume CPU registers are represented as global variables (see [General-Purpose Registers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-Purpose_Registers_.28GPR.29_-_16-bit_naming_conventions)).

```cpp
int AX, BX, SP, BP, ...;
int main(){...}
```

There is special CPU register (SP) that tracks the top of the stack.
SP is a pointer (holds a memory address like 0xAAAABBCC). But for the purposes of this post I'll use it as an array index (0, 1, 2, ...).

When a thread starts, `SP == STACK_CAPACITY` and then the program and OS modify it as needed. The rule is you can't write to stack cells beyond stack's top and any index less then SP is invalid and unsafe (because of [system interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)), so you
*first* decrement SP and *then* write a value to the newly allocated cell.

When you want to push several values in the stack in a row, you can reserve space for all of them upfront (*snippet #3*):

```cpp
SP -= 3;
stack[999] = 12;
stack[998] = 34;
stack[997] = stack[999] + stack[998];
```

*Note.* Now you can see why allocation on the stack is so fast - it's just a single register decrement.

---

**4. Local variables**

Let's take a look at this simplistic function (*snippet #4.1*):

```cpp
int triple(int a) {
    int result = a * 3;
    return result;
}
```

and rewrite it without using of local variable (*snippet #4.2*):

```cpp
int triple_noLocals(int a) {
    SP -= 1; // move pointer to unused cell, where we can store what we need
    stack[SP] = a * 3;
    return stack[SP];
}
```

and see how it is being called (*snippet #4.3*):

```cpp
// SP == 1000
someVar = triple_noLocals(11);
// now SP == 999, but we don't need the value at stack[999] anymore
// and we will move the stack index back, so we can reuse this cell later
SP += 1; // SP == 1000 again
```

---

**5. Push / pop**

Addition of a new element on the top of the stack is such a frequent operation, that CPUs have a special instruction for that, `push`.
We'll implent it like this (*snippet 5.1*):

```cpp
void push(int value) {
    --SP;
    stack[SP] = value;
}
```

Likewise, taking the top element of the stack (*snippet 5.2*):

```cpp
void pop(int& result) {
    result = stack[SP];
    ++SP; // note that `pop` decreases stack's size
}
```

Common usage pattern for push/pop is temporarily saving some value. Say, we have something useful in variable `myVar` and for some reason we need to do calculations which will overwrite it (*snippet 5.3*):

```cpp
int myVar = ...;
push(myVar); // SP == 999
myVar += 10;
... // do something with new value in myVar
pop(myVar); // restore original value, SP == 1000
```

---

**6. Function parameters**

Now let's pass parameters using stack (*snippet #6*):

```cpp
int triple_noL_noParams() { // `a` is at index 999, SP == 999
    SP -= 1; // SP == 998, stack[SP + 1] == a
    stack[SP] = stack[SP + 1] * 3;
    return stack[SP];
}

int main(){
    push(11); // SP == 999
    assert(triple(11) == triple_noL_noParams());
    SP += 2; // cleanup 1 local and 1 parameter
}
```

---

**7. `return` statement**

Let's return value in AX register (*snippet #7*):

```cpp
void triple_noL_noP_noReturn() { // `a` at 998, SP == 998
    SP -= 1; // SP == 997

    stack[SP] = stack[SP + 1] * 3;
    AX = stack[SP];

    SP += 1; // finally we can cleanup locals right in the function body, SP == 998
}

void main(){
    ... // some code
    push(AX); // save AX in case there is something useful there, SP == 999
    push(11); // SP == 998
    triple_noL_noP_noReturn();
    assert(triple(11) == AX);
    SP += 1; // cleanup param
             // locals were cleaned up in the function body, so we don't need to do it here
    pop(AX); // restore AX
    ...
}
```

---

**8. Stack base pointer (BP)** (also known as *frame pointer*) and **stack frame**

Lets take more "advanced" function and rewrite it in our asm-like C++ (*snippet #8.1*):

```cpp
int myAlgo(int a, int b) {
    int t1 = a * 3;
    int t2 = b * 3;
    return t1 - t2;
}

void myAlgo_noLPR() { // `a` at 997, `b` at 998, old AX at 999, SP == 997
    SP -= 2; // SP == 995

    stack[SP + 1] = stack[SP + 2] * 3; 
    stack[SP]     = stack[SP + 3] * 3;
    AX = stack[SP + 1] - stack[SP];

    SP += 2; // cleanup locals, SP == 997
}

int main(){
    push(AX); // SP == 999
    push(22); // SP == 998
    push(11); // SP == 997
    myAlgo_noLPR();
    assert(myAlgo(11, 22) == AX);
    SP += 2;
    pop(AX);
}
```

Now imagine we decided to introduce new local variable to store result there before returning, as we do in `tripple` (snippet #4.1). The body of the function will be (*snippet #8.2*):

```cpp
SP -= 3; // SP == 994
stack[SP + 2] = stack[SP + 3] * 3; 
stack[SP + 1] = stack[SP + 4] * 3;
stack[SP]     = stack[SP + 2] - stack[SP + 1];
AX = stack[SP];
SP += 3;
```

You see, we had to update every single reference to function parameters and local variables. To avoid that, we need an anchor index, which doesn't change when the stack grows.

We will create the anchor right upon function entry (before we allocate space for locals) by saving current top (value of SP) into BP register. *Snippet #8.3*:

```cpp
void myAlgo_noLPR_withAnchor() { // `a` at 997, `b` at 998, SP == 997
    push(BP);   // save old BP, SP == 996
    BP = SP;    // create anchor, stack[BP] == old value of BP, now BP == 996
    SP -= 2;    // SP == 994

    stack[BP - 1] = stack[BP + 1] * 3;
    stack[BP - 2] = stack[BP + 2] * 3;
    AX = stack[BP - 1] - stack[BP - 2];

    SP = BP;    // cleanup locals, SP == 996
    pop(BP);    // SP == 997
}
```

The slice of stack, wich belongs to and is in full control of the function is called **function's stack frame**. E.g. `myAlgo_noLPR_withAnchor`'s stack frame is `stack[996 .. 994]` (both idexes inclusive).
Frame starts at function's BP (after we've updated it inside function) and lasts until the next stack frame. So the parameters on the stack are part of the caller's stack frame (see note 8a).

Notes:
*8a.* [Wikipedia says otherwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) about parameters, but here I adhere to [Intel software developer's manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm), see vol. 1, section *6.2.4.1 Stack-Frame Base Pointer* and Figure 6-2 in section *6.3.2 Far CALL and RET Operation*. Function's parameters and stack frame are part of **function's activation record** (see [The gen on function perilogues](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/function-perilogues.html)).
*8b.* positive offsets from BP point to function parameters and negative offsets point to local variables. That's pretty handy for debugging
*8c.* `stack[BP]` stores the address of the previous stack frame, `stack[stack[BP]]` stores pre-previous stack frame and so on. Following this chain, you can discover frames of all the functions in the programm, which didn't return yet. This is how debuggers show you call stack
*8d.* the first 3 instructions of `myAlgo_noLPR_withAnchor`, where we setup the frame (save old BP, update BP, reserve space for locals) are called **function prologue**

---

**9. Calling conventions**

In snippet 8.1 we've pushed parameters for `myAlgo` from right to left and returned result in `AX`.
We could as well pass params left to right and return in `BX`. Or pass params in BX and CX and return in AX. Obviously, caller (`main()`) and
called function must agree where and in which order all this stuff is stored.

**Calling convention** is a set of rules on how parameters are passed and result is returned.

In the code above we've used *cdecl calling convention*:

- Parameters are passed on the stack, with the first argument at the lowest address on the stack at the time of the call (pushed last <...>). The caller is responsible for popping parameters back off the stack after the call.
- the return value is placed in AX
- EBP and ESP must be preserved by the callee (`myAlgo_noLPR_withAnchor` function in our case), such that the caller (`main` function) can rely on those registers not having been changed by a call.
- All other registers (EAX, <...>) may be freely modified by the callee; if a caller wishes to preserve a value before and after the function call, it must save the value elsewhere (we do this with AX)

<sup>(Source: example "32-bit cdecl" from Stack Overflow Documentation; copyright 2016 by [icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200291/icktoofay) and [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) ; licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0. An [archive of the full Stack Overflow Documentation content](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z) can be found at archive.org, in which this example is indexed by topic ID 3261 and example ID 11196.)</sup>

---

**10. Function calls**

Now the most interesting part. Just like data, executable code is also stored in memory (completely unrelated to memory for stack) and every instruction has an address.
When not commanded otherwise, CPU executes instructions one after another, in the order they are stored in memory. But we can command CPU to "jump" to another location in memory and execute instructions from there on.
In asm it can be any address, and in more high-level languages like C++ you can only jump to addresses marked by labels ([there are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8158007/264047) but they are not pretty, to say the least).

Let's take this function (*snippet #10.1*):

```cpp
int myAlgo_withCalls(int a, int b) {
    int t1 = triple(a);
    int t2 = triple(b);
    return t1 - t2;
}
```

And instead of calling `tripple` C++ way, do the following:

1. copy `tripple`'s code to the beginning of `myAlgo` body
2. at `myAlgo` entry jump over `tripple`'s code with `goto`
3. when we need to execute `tripple`'s code, save on the stack address of the code line just after `tripple` call, so we can return here later and continue execution (`PUSH_ADDRESS` macro below)
4. jump to the address of the 1st line (`tripple` function) and execute it to the end (3. and 4. together are `CALL` macro)
5. at the end of the `tripple` (after we've cleaned up locals), take return address from the top of the stack and jump there (`RET` macro)

Because there is no easy way to jump to particular code address in C++, we will use labels to mark places of jumps.
I won't go into detail how macros below work, just believe me they do what I say they do (*snippet #10.2*):

```cpp
// pushes the address of the code at label's location on the stack
// NOTE1: this gonna work only with 32-bit compiler (so that pointer is 32-bit and fits in int)
// NOTE2: __asm block is specific for Visual C++. In GCC use https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html
#define PUSH_ADDRESS(labelName) {               \
    void* tmpPointer;                           \
    __asm{ mov [tmpPointer], offset labelName } \
    push(reinterpret_cast<int>(tmpPointer));    \
}

// why we need indirection, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/13301627/264047
#define TOKENPASTE(x, y) x ## y
#define TOKENPASTE2(x, y) TOKENPASTE(x, y)

// generates token (not a string) we will use as label name. 
// Example: LABEL_NAME(155) will generate token `lbl_155`
#define LABEL_NAME(num) TOKENPASTE2(lbl_, num)

#define CALL_IMPL(funcLabelName, callId)    \
    PUSH_ADDRESS(LABEL_NAME(callId));       \
    goto funcLabelName;                     \
    LABEL_NAME(callId) :

// saves return address on the stack and jumps to label `funcLabelName`
#define CALL(funcLabelName) CALL_IMPL(funcLabelName, __LINE__)

// takes address at the top of stack and jump there
#define RET() {                                         \
    int tmpInt;                                         \
    pop(tmpInt);                                        \
    void* tmpPointer = reinterpret_cast<void*>(tmpInt); \
    __asm{ jmp tmpPointer }                             \
}

void myAlgo_asm() {
    goto my_algo_start;

triple_label:
    push(BP);
    BP = SP;
    SP -= 1;

    // stack[BP] == old BP, stack[BP + 1] == return address
    stack[BP - 1] = stack[BP + 2] * 3;
    AX = stack[BP - 1];

    SP = BP;     
    pop(BP);
    RET();

my_algo_start:
    push(BP);   // SP == 995
    BP = SP;    // BP == 995; stack[BP] == old BP, 
                // stack[BP + 1] == dummy return address, 
                // `a` at [BP + 2], `b` at [BP + 3]
    SP -= 2;    // SP == 993

    push(AX);
    push(stack[BP + 2]);
    CALL(triple_label);
    stack[BP - 1] = AX;
    SP -= 1;
    pop(AX);

    push(AX);
    push(stack[BP + 3]);
    CALL(triple_label);
    stack[BP - 2] = AX;
    SP -= 1;
    pop(AX);

    AX = stack[BP - 1] - stack[BP - 2];

    SP = BP; // cleanup locals, SP == 997
    pop(BP);
}

int main() {
    push(AX);
    push(22);
    push(11);
    push(7777); // dummy value, so that offsets inside function are like we've pushed return address
    myAlgo_asm();
    assert(myAlgo_withCalls(11, 22) == AX);
    SP += 1; // pop dummy "return address"
    SP += 2;
    pop(AX);
}
```

Notes:
*10a.* because return address is stored on the stack, in principle we can change it. This is how [stack smashing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) works
*10b.* the last 3 instructions at the "end" of `triple_label` (cleanup locals, restore old BP, return) are called **function's epilogue**

---

**11. Assembly**

Now let's look at real asm for `myAlgo_withCalls`. To do that in Visual Studio:

- set build platform to x86 (*not* x86_64)
- build type: Debug
- set break point somewhere inside myAlgo_withCalls
- run, and when execution stops at break point press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

One difference with our asm-like C++ is that asm's stack operate on bytes instead of ints. So to reserve space for one `int`, SP will be decremented by 4 bytes.
Here we go (*snippet #11.1*, line numbers in comments are from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/amalahov/7c8df89e2dfee956fd2577073981a22d?ts=4)):

```
;   114: int myAlgo_withCalls(int a, int b) {
 push        ebp        ; create stack frame 
 mov         ebp,esp  
; return address at (ebp + 4), `a` at (ebp + 8), `b` at (ebp + 12)
 
 sub         esp,0D8h   ; reserve space for locals. Compiler can reserve more bytes then needed. 0D8h is hexadecimal == 216 decimal 
 
 push        ebx        ; cdecl requires to save all these registers
 push        esi  
 push        edi  
 
 ; fill all the space for local variables (from (ebp-0D8h) to (ebp)) with value 0CCCCCCCCh repeated 36h times (36h * 4 == 0D8h)
 ; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3818856/264047
 ; I guess that's for ease of debugging, so that stack is filled with recognizable values
 ; 0CCCCCCCCh in binary is 110011001100...
 lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]     
 mov         ecx,36h    
 mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
 rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
 
;   115:    int t1 = triple(a);
 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]   ; push parameter `a` on the stack
 push        eax  
 
 call        triple (01A13E8h)  
 add         esp,4                   ; clean up param 
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax   ; copy result from eax to `t1`
 
;   116:    int t2 = triple(b);
 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch] ; push `b` (0Ch == 12)
 push        eax  
 
 call        triple (01A13E8h)  
 add         esp,4  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax ; t2 = eax
 
 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]   ; calculate and store result in eax
 sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  

 pop         edi  ; restore registers
 pop         esi  
 pop         ebx  
 
 add         esp,0D8h  ; check we didn't mess up esp or ebp. this is only for debug builds
 cmp         ebp,esp  
 call        __RTC_CheckEsp (01A116Dh)  
 
 mov         esp,ebp  ; destroy frame
 pop         ebp  
 ret
```

And asm for `tripple` (*snippet #11.2*):

```cpp
 push        ebp  
 mov         ebp,esp  
 sub         esp,0CCh  
 push        ebx  
 push        esi  
 push        edi  
 lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
 mov         ecx,33h  
 mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
 rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
 imul        eax,dword ptr [ebp+8],3  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
 pop         edi  
 pop         esi  
 pop         ebx  
 mov         esp,ebp  
 pop         ebp  
 ret
```

Hope, after reading this post, assembly doesn't look as cryptic as before :)

---

Here are links from the post's body and some further reading:

- [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky), [Where the top of the stack is on x86](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/) - top/bottom, push/pop, SP, stack frame, calling conventions
- [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky), [Stack frame layout on x86-64](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64) - args passing on x64, stack frame, red zone
- University of Mariland, [Understanding the Stack](https://web.archive.org/web/20171217113151/http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html) - a really well-written introduction to stack concepts. (It's for MIPS (not x86) and in GAS syntax, but this is insignificant for the topic). See other notes on [MIPS ISA Programming](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/index.html) if interested.
- x86 Asm wikibook, [General-Purpose Registers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-Purpose_Registers_.28GPR.29_-_16-bit_naming_conventions)
- x86 Disassembly wikibook, [The Stack](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack)
- x86 Disassembly wikibook, [Functions and Stack Frames](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames)
- [Intel software developer's manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) - I expected it to be really hardcore, but surprisingly it's pretty easy read (though amount of information is overwhelming)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard, [The gen on function perilogues](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/function-perilogues.html) - prologue/epilogue, stack frame/activation record, red zone

Comment: It was a long time ago that I asked this, that's a really great in depth answer. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the 16-bit names for registers in the early part of your answer?  If you were talking about actual 16-bit code, `[SP]` isn't a valid addressing 16-bit mode.  Probably best to use `ESP`.  Also, if you declare `SP` as an `int`, you should be modifying it by 4 for every element, not 1.  (If you declared `long *SP`, then `SP += 2` would increment by `2 * sizeof(int)`, and thus remove 2 elements.  But with `int` SP, that should be `SP += 8`, like `add esp, 8`. in 32-bit asm.

Comment: Fascinating! I think it's interesting that you try to explain assembly using C. I haven't seen that before. Neat. 

I might suggest renaming "No local variables" as "How local variables work", or just "Local variables".

Comment: @PeterCordes the reason for 16-bit names (SP, BP) is clarity - SP easily translates to "stack pointer". If I use proper 32-bit names I would need to either explain the difference between 16/32/64 bit modes or leave it unexplained. My intention was that someone who only knows Java or Python can follow the post without scratching head too much. And I think memory addressing would only distract the reader. Plus, I've put wikibook link on the topic for the curious and said couple words about ESP at the end of the post.

Comment: @DaveDopson glad you liked it! I've way overestimated my level of understanding of this stuff, so it took me hell lot of time - finding out a credible source for stack frame definition (wether it contains parameters or not) took like 4 hours alone

Comment: @Dave Regarding "No local variables" etc - I wanted headings to be in line with post's preface "asm programming is like C without local variables, ...", but I think you're right, so I've reworded them slightly. I'm not native English speaker, so you advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: *To avoid that, we need an anchor index, which doesn't change when the stack grows.*  Need is the wrong word; `-fomit-frame-pointer` has been the default in gcc and clang for years.  People looking at real asm need to know that EBP/RBP usually won't be used as a frame pointer.  I'd say "traditionally, humans wanted an anchor that doesn't change with push/pop, but compilers can keep track of changing offsets."  Then you can update the section about backtraces to say that's the legacy method, not used by default when DWARF `.eh_frame` metadata or Windows x86-64 metadata is available.

Comment: I'm also not a huge fan of showing every local variable having a stack address.  Usually compilers can avoid spilling them, and keep them in registers unless you compile with `-O0` to make unrealistic code for tiny functions.  You are showing functions that take args and return a value, so you can compile with -O3 just fine.  (But then you wouldn't be using the stack, and that's what you're trying to show...  hrm, maybe at least mention somewhere that optimization keeps things in registers, if you didn't already.)

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov - Explaining things well is really hard. To do so in one's second language is all the more challenging. Also, +1 to a few of the caveats pointed out by Peter. This content is an interesting take on an under-explained subject; would be cool to see it become some sort of stand-alone guide.   ps, if you haven't seen it before, check out Agner Fog's "instruction tables" and other guides. He's one of the better resources for low-level coding.

Comment: I know this question hasn't been active for a while but where are the arithmetic operation to the stack pointer performed? In order to access the individual local variables in a frame you must perform additions and subtractions with the pointer. Granted, you could just load up the stack pointer and offset into the ALU and calculate the address, but where would you store the result? Is there some auxiliary address register that is used for indirect addressing? Otherwise you would need to save it to RAM, which kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: @J.Lengel I don't know :) I would think that values like the result of `[ebp+8]` go directly from ALU to CPU's "fetcher" block (I don't know proper terminology), which then decides if value in that address can be taken from cache(s) or must be fetched from RAM etc. Probably @PeterCordes could clarify this.

Comment: So you are saying that there is probably an addressing mode that has these basic additive offsets to pointers built in (as part of the instruction arguments itself)? Or am I understanding that incorrectly?

Comment: @J.Lengel, I've started to write an answer to you, but I've decided to stop at ~1000 chars where almost every sentence contained "I *think*", "probably" or "speculation". You should really ask someone who knows the stuff better then me. You could search [Piters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:224132+[assembly])'s or [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky)'s posts, find an appropriate one and ask in comment there. Or post a brand new question and ping them or other expert.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll check that stuff out. Thanks for your effort though!

Answer (score 8):

Regarding whether the stack is implemented in the hardware, this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) might help.

> Some processors families, such as the
>   x86, have special instructions for
>   manipulating the stack of the
>   currently executing thread. Other
>   processor families, including PowerPC
>   and MIPS, do not have explicit stack
>   support, but instead rely on
>   convention and delegate stack
>   management to the operating system's
>   Application Binary Interface (ABI).

That article and the others it links to might be useful to get a feel for stack usage in processors.

Answer (score 5):

I think that main answer you are looking for has already been hinted at.

When an x86 computer boots up, the stack is not setup. The programmer must explicitly set it up at boot time. However, if you are already in an operating system, this has been taken care of. Below is a code sample from a simple bootstrap program.

First the data and stack segment registers are set, and then the stack pointer is set 0x4000 beyond that.

```
    movw    $BOOT_SEGMENT, %ax
    movw    %ax, %ds
    movw    %ax, %ss
    movw    $0x4000, %ax
    movw    %ax, %sp
```

After this code the stack may be used. Now I am sure it can be done in a number of different ways, but I think this should illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 5):

**The Concept**

First think of the whole thing as if you were the person who invented it. Like this:

First think of an array and how it is implemented at the low level --> it is basically just a set of contiguous memory locations (memory locations that are next to each other). Now that you have that mental image in your head, think of the fact that you can access ANY of those memory locations and delete it at your will as you remove or add data in your array. 
Now think of that same array but instead of the possibility to delete any location you decide that you will delete only the LAST location as you remove or add data in your array. 
Now your new idea to manipulate the data in that array in that way is called LIFO which means Last In First Out. Your idea is very good because it makes it easier to keep track of the content of that array without having to use a sorting algorithm every time you remove something from it. Also, to know at all times what the address of the last object in the array is, you dedicate one Register in the Cpu to keep track of it. Now, the  way that register keeps track of it is so that every time you remove or add something to your array you also decrement or increment the value of the address in your register by the amount of objects you removed or added from the array (by the amount of address space they occupied). You also want to make sure that that amount by which you decrement or increment that register is fixed to one amount (like 4 memory locations ie. 4 bytes) per object, again, to make it easier to keep track and also to make it possible to use that register with some loop constructs because loops use fixed incrementation per iteration (eg. to loop trough your array with a loop you construct the loop to increment your register by 4 each iteration, which would not be possible if your array has objects of different sizes in it). Lastly, you choose to call this new data structure a "Stack", because it reminds you of a stack of plates in a restaurant where they always remove or add a plate on the top of that stack.

**The Implementation**

As you can see a stack is nothing more than an array of contiguous memory locations where you decided how to manipulate it. Because of that you can see that you don't need to even use the special instructions and registers to control the stack. You can implement it yourself with the basic mov, add and sub instructions and using general purpose registers instead the ESP and EBP like this:

**mov edx, 0FFFFFFFFh**

**; -->** this will be the start address of your stack, furthest away from your code and data, it will also serve as that register that keeps track of the last object in the stack that i explained earlier. You call it the "stack pointer", so you choose the register EDX to be what ESP is normally used for.

**sub edx, 4**

**mov [edx], dword ptr [someVar]**

**; -->** these two instructions will decrement your stack pointer by 4 memory locations and copy the 4 bytes starting at [someVar] memory location to the memory location that EDX now points to, just like a PUSH instruction decrements the ESP, only here you did it manually and you used EDX. So the PUSH instruction is basically just a shorter opcode that actually does this with ESP.

**mov eax, dword ptr [edx]**

**add edx, 4**

**; -->** and here we do the opposite, we first copy the 4 bytes starting at the memory location that EDX now points to into the register EAX (arbitrarily chosen here, we could have copied it anywhere we wanted). And then we increment our stack pointer EDX by 4 memory locations. This is what the POP instruction does.

Now you can see that the instructions PUSH and POP and the registers ESP ans EBP were just added by Intel to make the above concept of the "stack" data structure easier to write and read. There are still some RISC (Reduced Instruction Set) Cpu-s that don't have the PUSH ans POP instructions and dedicated registers for stack manipulation, and while writing assembly programs for those Cpu-s you have to implement the stack by yourself just like i showed you.

Answer (score 4):

The stack is just a way that programs and functions use memory.

The stack always confused me, so I made an illustration:

[image: The stack is like stalactites]

([svg version here](http://openclipart.org/people/alexander256/stalactites.svg))

- A push "attaches a new stalactite to the ceiling".
- A pop "pops off a stalactite".

Hope it's more helpful than confusing.

Feel free to use the SVG image (CC0 licensed).

Answer (score 3):

You confuse an abstract stack and the hardware implemented stack. The latter is already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The stack is "implemented" by means of the stack pointer, which (assuming x86 architecture here) points into the stack *segment*. Every time something is pushed on the stack (by means of pushl, call, or a similar stack opcode), it is written to the address the stack pointer points to, and the stack pointer *decremented* (stack is growing *downwards*, i.e. smaller addresses). When you pop something off the stack (popl, ret), the stack pointer is *incremented* and the value read off the stack.

In a user-space application, the stack is already set up for you when your application starts. In a kernel-space environment, you have to set up the stack segment and the stack pointer first...

Answer (score 2):

The call stack is implemented by the x86 instruction set and the operating system.

Instructions like push and pop adjust the stack pointer while the operating system takes care of allocating memory as the stack grows for each thread.

The fact that the x86 stack "grows down" from higher to lower addresses make this architecture more [susceptible to the buffer overflow attack.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290051.aspx#vctchcompilersecuritychecksindepthanchor3)

Comment: Why does the fact that the x86 stack grows down make it more susceptible to buffer overflows?  Couldn't you get the same overflow with an expand up segment?

Comment: @nathan: only if you can get the application to allocate a negative amount of memory on the stack.

Comment: Buffer overflow attacks write past the end of a stack based array - char userName[256], this writes memory from lower to higher which lets you overwrite things like the return address. If the stack grew in the same direction, you would only be able to overwrite unallocated stack.

Comment: I've been reading that what distinguishes the stack from the heap is that the stack *cannot grow* in size, are you saying that the contents of the stack grows, or the stack itself?

Answer (score 1):

The stack already exists, so you can assume that when writing your code.
The stack contains the return addresses of the functions, the local variables and the variables which are passed between functions.
There are also stack registers such as BP, SP (Stack Pointer) built-in that you can use, hence the built-in commands you have mentioned.
If the stack wasn't already implemented, functions couldn't run, and code flow couldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the Gas assembler specifically, but in general the stack is "implemented" by maintaining a reference to the location in memory where the top of the stack resides. The memory location is stored in a register, which has different names for different architectures, but can be thought of as the stack pointer register.

The pop and push commands are implemented in most architectures for you by building upon micro instructions. However, some "Educational Architectures" require you implement them your self. Functionally, push would be implemented somewhat like this:

```
   load the address in the stack pointer register to a gen. purpose register x
   store data y at the location x
   increment stack pointer register by size of y
```

Also, some architectures store the last used memory address as the Stack Pointer. Some store the next available address.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching about how stack works in terms of function and i found [this blog](http://www.cryptroix.com/journey-to-the-stack/) its awesome and its explain concept of stack from scratch and how stack store value in stack.

Now on your answer . I will explain with python but you will get good idea how stack works in any language.

[image]

Its a program :

```
def hello(x):
    if x==1:
        return "op"
    else:
        u=1
        e=12
        s=hello(x-1)
        e+=1
        print(s)
        print(x)
        u+=1
    return e

hello(3)
```

[image]

[image]

Source : [Cryptroix](http://www.cryptroix.com/journey-to-the-stack/)

some of its topic which it cover in blog:

```
How Function work ?
Calling a Function
 Functions In a Stack
 What is Return Address
 Stack
Stack Frame
Call Stack
Frame Pointer (FP) or Base Pointer (BP)
Stack Pointer (SP)
Allocation stack and deallocation of stack
StackoverFlow
What is Heap?
```

But its explain with python language so if you want you can take a look.

Comment: Criptoix site is dead and there is no copy on web.archive.org

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov Cryptroix was not working due to hosting issue. Cryptroix is up now and working.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a stack is a data structure.  Often, data structures (stacks included) you work with are abstract and exist as a representation in memory.

The stack you are working with in this case has a more material existence- it maps directly to real physical registers in the processor.  As a data structure, stacks are FILO (first in, last out) structures that ensure data is removed in the reverse order it was entered.  See the StackOverflow logo for a visual! ;)

You are working with the *instruction stack*.  This is the stack of actual instructions you are feeding the processor.

Comment: wrong.  this isn't an 'instruction stack' (is there such a thing?) this is simply a memory accessed via the Stack register.  used for temporary storage, procedure parameters, and (most important) return address for function calls

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a stack is 'just' a data structure. Here, however, it refers to a hardware implemented stack used for a special purpose --"The Stack".

Many people have commented about hardware implemented stack versus the (software)stack data structure. I would like to add that there are three major stack structure types -

1. A call stack -- Which is the one you are asking about!
   It stores function parameters and return address etc. Do read Chapter 4 ( All about 4th page i.e. page 53)functions in that book. There is a good explanation.
2. A generic stack
   Which you might use in your program to do something special...
3. A generic hardware stack
   I am not sure about this, but I remember reading somewhere that there is a general purpose hardware implemented stack available in some architectures. If anyone knows whether this is correct, please do comment.

The first thing to know is the architecture you are programming for, which the book explains (I just looked it up --link). To really understand things, I suggest that you learn about the memory, addressing, registers and architecture of x86 (I assume thats what you are learning --from the book).

Answer (score 0):

Calling functions, which requires saving and restoring local state in LIFO fashion (as opposed to say, a generalized co-routine approach), turns out to be such an incredibly common need that assembly languages and CPU architectures basically build this functionality in.  The same could probably be said for notions of threading, memory protection, security levels, etc.  In theory you could implement your own stack, calling conventions, etc., but I assume some opcodes and most existing runtimes rely on this native concept of "stack".

Answer (score 0):

What is Stack?
A stack is a type of data structure -- a means of storing information in a computer. When a new object is entered in a stack, it is placed on top of all the previously entered objects. In other words, the stack data structure is just like a stack of cards, papers, credit card mailings, or any other real-world objects you can think of. When removing an object from a stack, the one on top gets removed first. This method is referred to as LIFO (last in, first out).

The term "stack" can also be short for a network protocol stack. In networking, connections between computers are made through a series of smaller connections. These connections, or layers, act like the stack data structure, in that they are built and disposed of in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`stack` is part of memory. it use for `input` and `output` of `functions`. also it use for remembering function's return.

`esp` register is remember the stack address.

`stack` and `esp` are implemented by hardware. also you can implement it yourself. it will make your program very slow.

example:

nop // `esp` = 0012ffc4

push 0 //`esp` = 0012ffc0 ,Dword[0012ffc0]=00000000

call proc01 // `esp` = 0012ffbc ,Dword[0012ffbc] = `eip` , `eip` = adrr[proc01]

pop `eax` // `eax` = Dword[`esp`], `esp` = `esp` + 4