# How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86-64, nasm

Using NASM and Mingw-w64 I've been trying to run the following program which is supposed to print a message to the screen using the Windows API. It runs, but nothing shows on the console and it results in an invalid access to memory location (error code 0x3e6h). Why is that, and how can I get the program to run properly?

```
global main
extern ExitProcess
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile

section .text
main:
    mov     rcx,                  0fffffff5h
    call    GetStdHandle

    mov     rcx,                  rax
    mov     rdx,                  NtlpBuffer
    mov     r8,                   NtnNBytesToWrite
    mov     r9,                   NtlpNBytesWritten
    mov     dword [rsp - 04h],    00h
    call    WriteFile
ExitProgram:
    mov     rcx,                  00h
    call    ExitProcess

section .data
NtlpBuffer:        db    'Hello, World!', 00h
NtnNBytesToWrite:  dd    0eh

section .bss
NtlpNBytesWritten: resd  01h
```

Compiled by

```
nasm -f win64 test.asm
gcc -s -o test.exe test.obj
```

Comment: Did you try to write small C program which calls `WriteFile`, and see its disassembly in 64-bit build?

Comment: Yes, but it makes me a little more confused because I'm not used to looking over compiler optimized code. I tend to just trust what the compiler shoots out when writing a C program.

Answer (score 6):

`[rsp-04h]` is addressing below the stack pointer, that's a bad idea. Whatever you write there will be overwritten by the `call` anyway.
Looks like you need to brush up on your knowledge of the calling convention. Shadow space for the 4 arguments in registers have to be allocated and further arguments must be placed on top of them.

Also, the number of bytes to write should be the actual number, not a pointer.

```
global main
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile

section .text
main:
    sub     rsp, 40          ; reserve shadow spaceand align the stack by 16
    mov     ecx, -11         ; GetStdHandle takes a DWORD arg, write it as 32-bit.  This is STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call    GetStdHandle

    mov     rcx, rax
    mov     rdx, NtlpBuffer         ; or better, lea rdx, [rel NtlpBuffer]
    mov     r8, [NtnNBytesToWrite]  ; or better, make it an EQU constant for mov r8d, bytes_to_write
    mov     r9, NtlpNBytesWritten   ; first 4 args in regs
    mov     qword [rsp + 32], 00h   ; fifth arg on the stack above the shadow space.  Also, this is a pointer so it needs to be a qword store.
    call    WriteFile
    add     rsp, 40
ExitProgram:
    xor     eax, eax
    ret

section .data
NtlpBuffer:        db    'Hello, World!', 00h
NtnNBytesToWrite:  dq    0eh

section .bss
NtlpNBytesWritten: resd  01h
```

See [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) re: using RIP-relative LEA instead of `mov reg, imm64` to put addresses into registers.

The trailing `0` byte in the string isn't needed; `WriteFile` takes pointer + length, not an implicit-length C string.  You might want to use `db 'Hello...', 13,10` to include a newline.  (DOS CR LF.)

On function entry, `RSP%16 == 8`.  `sub rsp, 40` will reserve the 32 bytes of shadow space, and an extra 8 bytes to make `RSP%16 == 0` since we don't `push` anything.  This gets us ready for another `call` that pushes an 8-byte return address which will make `RSP%16 == 8` on entry to the callee.

See also [Hello World using NASM (and GoLink) on x64 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77114093/hello-world-using-nasm-and-golink-on-x64-64-bit-windows/77136275#77136275) for a tidied up version of this Hello World using RIP-relative LEA, less static storage, and not hard-coding the string length.

Comment: That all makes sense now, I really should hit the books some more. So many of the mistakes I made were pretty easy to make for a beginner, but I feel that I have a little better grasp now. Thank you.

Comment: When I run the executable generated with this code, the ExitProcess part works accurately, however I see no strings emitted to the console.

Comment: `GetStdHandle` takes a `DWORD` arg; it would make more sense to do `mov ecx, 0fffffff5h`.  Or `mov ecx, -11`.  Also, with `default rel`, the normal way to get pointers into registers is `lea  rdx, [NtlpBuffer]`.  And `NtnNBytesToWrite` should just be an `equ` constant, not a value to load from memory.

Comment: Also, this is broken: `sub  rsp, 40` needs to be *before*  `call GetStdHandle`, otherwise main's return address will be part of the shadow space to that call and get trashed.

Comment: (edited to fix those things.)