# Assembly pe64 gui win64 WriteFile shows nothing

Tags: assembly, fasm

This is my source code which Must shows 'Hello, World!' Message but shows nothing !

```
FORMAT PE64 GUI
ENTRY start

SECTION '.text' CODE READABLE EXECUTABLE

start:
        mov     rcx, -11
        call    [GetStdHandle]

        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     rdx, msg
        mov     r8d, 13
        mov     r9, MSG_WRITTEN_BYTES
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     QWORD [rsp+32], 0
        call    [WriteFile]
        add     rsp, 40

        xor     rcx, rcx
        call    [ExitProcess]


section '.data' data readable writeable

  msg: db 'Hello World!',0

SECTION '.idata' IMPORT DATA READABLE WRITABLE

        DD      0,0,0,RVA KERNEL32,RVA KERNEL32F          ; KERNEL32.DLL
        DD      0,0,0,0,0

        KERNEL32:      DB 'KERNEL32.DLL',0

        KERNEL32F:
                ExitProcess     DQ RVA _ExitProcess
                GetStdHandle    DQ RVA _GetStdHandle
                WriteFile       DQ RVA _WriteFile
                                DQ 0

        _ExitProcess:   DB 0,0,'ExitProcess',0
        _GetStdHandle:  DB 0,0,'GetStdHandle',0
        _WriteFile:     DB 0,0,'WriteFile',0

SECTION '.bss' READABLE WRITABLE

        MSG_WRITTEN_BYTES: RQ 1
```

Everything looks good !! but i don't know why nothing shows ! i also got no error and i can't find anything with debug !

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `WriteFile` correctly -- you still need to allocate space on the stack for the callee to save the registers (see the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019)).

Check out this SO answer for a working example:
[How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902157/how-to-properly-call-64-bit-windows-api-in-assembly)

Comment: i just updated the source code and still i have problem with it

Comment: @ELHASKSERVERS: Change `SECTION '.text' CODE READABLE WRITABLE` to `SECTION '.text' CODE READABLE EXECUTABLE`.

Comment: now there is no error but still WriteFile shows nothing !