# Call function with more than 4 parameters in ASM 64 bit, Windows 10

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, fasm

I compile the following code snippet in FASM 64bit for Windows 10, I generate my BIN, I import it in another language that runs this with CallWindProc, it works great when it is for a function with 4 parameters, what should I add to Can I call a function with 12 or more parameters, for example? I appreciate any suggestions.

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 20h
mov     r9,  04A4B404h      ; param_04 - 04A4B404h
mov     r8,  03A3B303h      ; param_03 - 03A3B303h
mov     rdx, 02A2B202h      ; param_02 - 02A2B202h
mov     rcx, 01A1B101h      ; param_01 - 01A1B101h  
mov     rax, 00A0B000h      ; ptr funtion - 00A0B000h
call    rax
add     rsp, 20h
pop     rbp
retn
```

Try this but it doesn't work

```
mov     rax, 05A5B505h                  ; param_05 - 05A5B505h
mov     rsp, rax
```

Comment: Usually, additional parameters are expected to be pushed on the stack. Modifying the stack pointer is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Except you normally don't literally `push`, because the stack args have to be above the shadow space, and you only want to reserve that once at the top of the function.  So you do modify the stack pointer, but with a small relative modification, indeed not by setting a whole new value!

Comment: [Hello World using NASM (and GoLink) on x64 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77114093) shows how to call `WriteFile` with 5 args.  Also [How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24902157) for just that.