# Generate a random number using the C Preprocessor

Tags: random, c-preprocessor

I would like to generate a random number or string using the **C** Preprocessor ... um ... I don't even know if this is possible, but I am trying to create variables on the fly (strings would be helpful here) and assign them values (integers). So there are a few things I am trying to do but the basic question remains - can I create a random string or number using the preprocessor.

Comment: In short: no. You will have to write a simple preprocessor of your own. Don't forget to design a way test your random source code.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/NEWS4/RANDC.HTM `1999-01-15 Jeff Stout`

Comment: Do you really need *random* or do you just need *unique* ? If the latter then maybe use `__LINE__` to create unique variable names ?

Comment: I think Paul identified what the OP really wants to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I take your question that you want to have a way of creating unique identifier tokens through the preprocessor.

gcc has an extension that is called `__COUNTER__` and does what you expect from its name. You can combine this with macro concatenation `##` to obtain unique identifiers.

If you have a C99 compiler you can use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/). It has macros called `P99_LINEID` and `P99_FILEID`. They can be used as

```
#include "p99_id.h"

P99_LINEID(some, other, tokens, to, make, it, unique, on, the, line)
```

and similarily for `P99_FILEID`.

The first mangles a name from your tokens and the line number and a hash that depends on the number of times the file "p99_id.h" had been included. The second macro just uses that hash and not the line number such that a name is reproducible at several places inside the same compilation unit.

These two macros also have counterparts `P99_LINENO` and `P99_FILENO` that just produce large numbers instead of identifier tokens.

Comment: Isn't that extension `__COUNTER__`? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: Wanted to add that `__COUNTER__` is also available for other compilers like [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). Just be aware that `__COUTER__` is only unique for the file the pre-processor is currently parsing (it starts with `0` for each source file parsed).

Answer (score 22):

Based on  [1999-01-15 Jeff Stout](http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/NEWS4/RANDC.HTM)  (thanks to @rlb.usa)

```
#define UL unsigned long
#define znew  ((z=36969*(z&65535)+(z>>16))<<16)
#define wnew  ((w=18000*(w&65535)+(w>>16))&65535)
#define MWC   (znew+wnew)
#define SHR3  (jsr=(jsr=(jsr=jsr^(jsr<<17))^(jsr>>13))^(jsr<<5))
#define CONG  (jcong=69069*jcong+1234567)
#define KISS  ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)
/*  Global static variables: 
    (the seed changes on every minute) */
static UL z=362436069*(int)__TIMESTAMP__, w=521288629*(int)__TIMESTAMP__, \
   jsr=123456789*(int)__TIMESTAMP__, jcong=380116160*(int)__TIMESTAMP__;


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    cout<<KISS<<endl;
    cout<<KISS<<endl;
    cout<<KISS<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
247524236
3009541994
1129205949
```

Comment: Very good implementation for an embedded system. Both answers are good.

Comment: What does it mean: "the seed changes on every minute"? What event changes it?

Comment: @user10133158 `__TIMESTAMP__` is a compiler variable that has a 1-minute precision. So, every different minute you compile, the seed changes

Comment: This is misleading because it does not use the preprocessor to compute a random number, as OP requested. Instead it inserts a block of C code that will be compiled into code that computes a number.

Comment: @ScottJ No, the code is at preprocessor stage

Comment: @nergeia Nonsense. Run it with `gcc -E` (preproccesor only) to see the result:     cout<<(((((z=36969*(z&65535)+(z>>16))<<16)+((w=18000*(w&65535)+(w>>16))&65535))^(jcong=69069*jcong+1234567))+(jsr=(jsr=(jsr=jsr^(jsr<<17))^(jsr>>13))^(jsr<<5)))<<endl;