# C++20 __FILE__ __LINE replacement when creating a variable in a macro

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, c++20

I am trying to update my code to C++20 and I have realised that my performance logging macros aren't working.

Current code:

```
#define LN_PROFILE(info) timer::ScopeTimer timer##__FILE__##__LINE__(__FUNCSIG__, info);
```

(ScopeTimer stores its results when its destructed)

Using std::source_location::current I could not manage to concatenate it to end of my variable name.
(My macro is written as such to avoid two timers being created with the same name, messing up the code.)

Comment: `__FILE__` expands to a string literal. You cannot concatenate it with anything. Why do you need it? Just use `__LINE__`. It's not like you need to declare timers at the file scope. Or do you?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5355730/10961484