# Creating macro using __LINE__ for different variable names

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating C macro with ## and **LINE** (token concatenation with positioning macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597007/creating-c-macro-with-and-line-token-concatenation-with-positioning-macr)

I am trying to use the `__LINE__` macro to generate different variable names. I have a scoped benchmark class called Benchmark(located in the utils namespace) and it's constructor takes a string. Here is the macro definition I have created:

```
#define BENCHMARK_SCOPE utils::Benchmark bm##__LINE__(std::string(__FUNCTION__))
```

Unfortunately this causes the following error:

`<some_file_name>(59): error C2374: 'bm__LINE__' : redefinition; multiple initialization`

This leads me to the conclusion the `__LINE__` macros does not get expanded. I have created my macross according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675203/812912). Do you have ideas why `__LINE__` does not get expanded?

**EDIT**: probably the compiler info is also relevent. I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried `bm## __LINE__` (with a space)?

Comment: @Cameron I did thanks to your comment but nothing has changed.

Comment: OK, one more hack to try: `#define _BENCHMARK_SCOPE(line) utils::Benchmark bm##line(...` with `#define BENCHMARK_SCOPE _BENCHMARK_SCOPE(__LINE__)`

Comment: @Cameron - still not working. Here is an example on ideone: http://ideone.com/5r5l1 (tried to make it as simple as possible)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use combination of 2 macros:

```
#define COMBINE1(X,Y) X##Y  // helper macro
#define COMBINE(X,Y) COMBINE1(X,Y)
```

And then use it as,

```
COMBINE(x,__LINE__);
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of why do I need to use two macros for that?

Comment: @izomorphius, Actually your question is a duplicate of another one, where it is explained nicely. I have commented that to your question, plz check it.

Answer (score 6):

You're using token pasting.  This occurs *before* the recursive macro
expansion (so that you can token paste to get the name of a macro you
want to invoke).  Thus:

```
#define PASTE(a,b) a ## b
```

will paste the exact arguments passed to `PASTE`, then try to expand
the resulting new token.  To get the effect you want, you need an
additional level of indirection:

```
#define PASTE_HELPER(a,b) a ## b
#define PASTE(a,b) PASTE_HELPER(a,b)
```

Here, the arguments to `PASTE` will be expanded before `PASTE_HELPER` is
invoked.

Answer (score 5):

try this code, I've used it in an older project

```
#define CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2)
#ifdef _MSC_VER // Necessary for edit & continue in MS Visual C++.
# define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __COUNTER__)
#else
# define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __LINE__)
#endif 


int ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(var)
```

EDIT:

I think you should use **COUNTER** in visual studio only if also using precompiled headers.

Comment: It worked with __LINE__ as well.