# Pre-processor directive to concatenate a symbol with a variable value in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, avr-gcc

This is how symbol concatenation is done in **C**.

`#define conc(a,b) a ## b`

eg:

`conc(hello,World)` will make the symbol `helloWorld`.

What I need to know is a bit different. Say there's a variable `n` that hold some integer. Now I need to create a symbol by concatenating another symbol with the **value of** `n`.

Eg:

`n = 2`
I need to define some `function(...)` so that `function(symbol,n)` will give `symbol1` (not `symboln`) and when `n = 3`, `function(symbol,n)` will give `symbol3` etc...

How can I define something like that?

---

This is what i really want to achieve. First, this is to be used to in `AtmelStudio` to program an `atmega` micro-controller. There are 4 `USART` modules there so are seperate set of registers, which change there names only by the number of the module.

For example, the four baud rate registers in four modules are `UBRR0L`, `UBRR1L`, `UBRR2L`, `UBRR3L`. (and there are several more, see below).

[image]

I need to write a function to initialize a given module by setting up values of the relevant registers. Since the register names vary only by the module number, if I can define some pre-processor directive as asked in this post, I can write a single function representing register names by some symbols, so the symbols will be bear relevant register names and the thing will go fine..

Eg:

If i can define `conc(a,b)` to do what I need, a simple function

```
void init(int no){
    conc(UBRR,no) = 0xF0;
}
```

Will be able to use to represent all the followings;

```
UBRR0 = 0xF0;
UBRR1 = 0xF0;
UBRR2 = 0xF0;
UBRR3 = 0xF0;
```

If this is not achievable, only thing I know is to re-write four separate functions. But hope there will be better alternatives..

Comment: have a look at this question I have posted a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379691/creating-macro-using-line-for-different-variable-names Still this will only work for constants, not for variables.

Comment: Please give us more context on what you want to achieve. You mean a variable or another macro that you want to expand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preprocessor will operate on your code, BEFORE compilation & obviously much before run time. So no preprocessor directive can solve your purpose.

The closest match would be to use a switch case as below:

```
switch(n){
case 0: ptr=&symbol0; break;
case 1: ptr=&symbol1; break;
case 2: ptr=&symbol2; break;
case 3: ptr=&symbol3; break;
case 4: ptr=&symbol4; break;
case 5: ptr=&symbol5; break;
//etc... needs to be filled manually.
}
```

& then operate on `*ptr`...

Also if your variable names are going to be sequential, why not have an array, with name as symbol & `symbol0` changed to `symbol[0]` ?

EDIT:
Saw the edit in the question now.
You can have switch case as shown above, or create an array of pointers, which will hold `UBRR0L`, `UBRR0L` etc. & then use it with index. As much as I know, they are just registers & will be present at fixed addresses.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it using the C preprocessor because the values of variables are determined at runtime.  But you can use `snprintf()` to build strings based on numbers like that at runtime.

Comment: Ok, i need to use this in `avrgcc` to program a micro-controller. So `snprintf()` won't help. I'll have to look for some other way. Thanks for the answer anyway..

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us why snprintf() can't be used?

Comment: please see the updated post. I'm not much experienced. There may be better ways to do that. If so, just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that the registers (for example RXC0, RXC1, RXC2, etc.) are equidistant. If this assumption is true you can calculate the address of the following register (simply replace `rint` by the type of the register):

```
rint *
register_address(rint *first, rint *second, unsigned int n)
{
    size_t diff = second - first;

    return first + diff * n;
}
```

Your `init()` function would then look like that:

```
void
init(int no)
{
    *register_address(&UBRR0, &UBRR1, no) = 0xF0;
}
```

This function call can be simplified/hidden by a macro:

```
#define register_value(name, no) *register_address(&conc(name, 0), &conc(name, 1), no)
```

so you can write:

```
void
init(int no)
{
    register_value(UBRR, no) = 0xF0;
}
```

This code is untested and I'm not sure if it really works. If it works and you are going to use it, I would test the assumption by a static assert.

Answer (score 0):

The real trick is the following:

```
#define TIMER_0     0
#define TIMER_1     1
#define TIMER_2     2

#define _SET_TIMER_NORMAL_MODE(val)        TCCR ## val &= ~(1 << WGM ## val ## 0)
#define SET_TIMER_NORMAL_MODE(instance)     _SET_TIMER_NORMAL_MODE(instance)
```

Now we can use it as:

```
SET_TIMER_NORMAL_MODE(TIMER_0)
```

which expands to:

```
 _SET_TIMER_NORMAL_MODE(0)
```

furthermore, this expands to:

```
TCCR0 &= ~(1 << WGM00)
```