# __COUNTER__ in variable name

Tags: c++, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

I have seen this question:

[How to generate random variable names in C++ using macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082192/how-to-generate-random-variable-names-in-c-using-macros)

with the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675203/551045

And I've tried to implement it in clang.

Here is my declaration:

```
#define TRACE(stream) FuncTrace x#__COUNTER__ (llvm::errs(), "hallo", 1)
```

I tried all variations `x##__COUNTER__; x ## __COUNTER__` and so on but none seem to work.

Could this be a  clang bug? The clang [help](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) page says it has the `__COUNTER__` macro.

In the end the macro I need something like this:

```
#define TRACE(stream) FuncTrace x#__COUNTER__ (stream, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. To concatenate two tokens into one you use the `##` operator. The `#` operator is used to turn a token into a string.
2. `x ## __COUNTER__` will just produce `x__COUNTER__`. You need to fully expand `__COUNTER__` first. One possible method is add a few more indirections, e.g.

   ```
   #define YTRACE(x, y) FuncTrace x##y (llvm::errs(), __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
   #define XTRACE(x, y) YTRACE(x, y)
   #define TRACE(x) XTRACE(x, __COUNTER__)
   ```

Comment: That's pretty much it. I had the wrong syntax when i tried this indirection approach.