# How can I construct a locally unique identifier name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, uniqueidentifier, c-preprocessor

I want to create a unique variable name on the fly.

This is my code:

```
int call(int i)
{
    return i;
}
 
#define XCAT3(a, b, c)    a ## b ## c
 
#define CALL_2(arg, place, line) int XCAT3(cl, place, line) = call(arg);
 
#define CALL_1(arg)    CALL_2(arg, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CALL_1(1); /* this is line 20 */
    return 0;
}
```

This does work in GCC (http://ideone.com/p4BKQ) but unfortunately not in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012.

The error message is:

> test.cpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'function_string'
>
> test.cpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
>
> test.cpp(20): error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value

How can I create an on-the-fly unique variable name with C++?

**Solution:**

```
#define CAT2(a,b) a##b
#define CAT(a,b) CAT2(a,b)
#define UNIQUE_ID CAT(_uid_,__COUNTER__)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int UNIQUE_ID = 1;
    int UNIQUE_ID = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082192/how-to-generate-random-variable-names-in-c-using-macros

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a unique identifier, many implementations offer the `__COUNTER__` preprocessor macro, that expands to an ever increasing number with every use.

```
#define CAT(a,b) CAT2(a,b) // force expand
#define CAT2(a,b) a##b // actually concatenate
#define UNIQUE_ID() CAT(_uid_,__COUNTER__)

auto UNIQUE_ID() = call(1); // may be _uid_0
auto UNIQUE_ID() = call(2); // may be _uid_1
```

Comment: +1, that is good to know, but i'd really like to know what's wrong with my code :|

Comment: @Felix: As was said, `__FUNCTION__` yields a string literal like `"main"`, not something that can be used as part of an identifier. Actually, your code shouldn't compile at all, not even on GCC.

Comment: Accepted because this is what I need, but: I started a Visual Studio 2008 default commandline project and another one in VS2012, and in neither one them the __COUNTER__ gets expanded. Complete source: `#define UNIQUE_ID uid##__COUNTER__

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int UNIQUE_ID = 1;
    int UNIQUE_ID = 2;
    return 0;
}` gives the error `error C2374: 'uid__COUNTER__' : redefinition; multiple initialization` have you got an idea why?

Comment: @Felix: Good question. Try `#define EXPAND(Arg) Arg` and `#define UNIQUE_ID() _uid_ ## EXPAND(__COUNTER__)`.

Comment: That cannot work because the ## paste operator takes its arguments literally. But to EXPAND the counter is a good idea and worked! Now I just have to get it pasted correctly ...

Comment: @Felix: Well... `#define CAT(a,b) CAT2(a,b)`, `#define CAT2(a,b) a##b`, `#define UNIQUE_ID() CAT(_uid_,__COUNTER__)` should work in this case. May or may not need `EXPAND` around `__COUNTER__`.

Comment: The additional level of indirection worked! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to defer token pasting until after the parameters `place` and `line` are recursively expanded in the macro `CALL_LATER2`.  You do that by moving the `##` operations to a separate macro -- as long as `##` does not appear in the body of `CALL_LATER2`, all of its arguments will be prescanned for macros:

```
#define XCAT3(a, b, c)    a ## b ## c
#define CALL_LATER2(fun, h, place, line) \
    auto XCAT3(calllater, place, line) = \
        call_later((fun), (h));
```

However, this still won't do what you want, as `__FUNCTION__` expands to a string with `"` characters, not to something that can be pasted into an identifier.  You need to instead just base your created name off `__LINE__` and ensure that the fact that you can end up with duplicates in different compilation units is not a problem (If they're local to some function, that should be fine, or you can put them in an anonymous namespace.)

Comment: This still does not work for me – please see my updated question