# Generate a unique variable name with MACRO __COUNTER__ and use it twice?

Tags: c++, macros

I’m trying to generate a unique variable name with a MACRO, but then immediately reference it again in the same code module, and I cannot figure out if it’s possible.

I am using __ COUNTER __ because I cannot use __ LINE __; this appears in multiple .cpp modules and line numbers could be the same.

For example:

```
#define MY_VAR JOIN( myVar, __COUNTER__  )
#define JOIN( symbol1, symbol2 ) _DO_JOIN( symbol1, symbol2 )
#define _DO_JOIN( symbol1, symbol2 ) symbol1##symbol2

int MY_VAR = 5;

void someFunction(&MY_VAR)
{
...
}
```

What happens is that **COUNTER** is incremented twice, so the second occurrence does not match the first one.

This post seems to imply that it’s not possible in some of the comments; however, as it is rather old, I wonder if a solution has occurred to anyone:

[How to generate random variable names in C++ using macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082192/how-to-generate-random-variable-names-in-c-using-macros)

EDIT: (add explanation of usage case)
I have inherited some old code that I need to port. There are several hundred .cpp files that each declare a static variable (outside of any class), and since they were originally auto-generated by some script, they all use the same variable name. This is not a problem since the static variable normally is only inside that .cpp module. that variable is then passed to an object creation function, so it is used TWICE.

However, I am turning it into a JUCE (C++ framework) module, and as such all the .cpp files are essentially #included into one .cpp file; hence, all of these same-named variables cause redefined symbol errors.

I was looking for a macro that would automatically generate a unique name within each .cpp file, however as I said the variable is referenced twice in each file. Hope that makes some sense!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What actual problem are you trying to solve using this technique?

Comment: You could use a real compile time counter instead of a macro.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I added the usage case to the original post.

Comment: @Mechap - do you have any example of how that would work?

Comment: In this case, I think you could just do `#define name_of_static_variable __FILE__##__LINE__` That would let you not have to change the code base as well as create the N unique names that you need.

Comment: @NathanOliver - that doesn't work, as I end up with the full pathname of the file on my hard drive and it can't become a variable name.

Comment: Write a quick program that goes through each cpp file and renames any occurrence of `name_of_static_variable` to be some unique name your program generates for each file?