# What does the "rep stos" x86 assembly instruction sequence do?

Tags: assembly, x86

I recently stumbled across the following assembly instruction sequence:

```
rep stos    dword ptr [edi]
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For `ecx` repetitions, stores the contents of `eax` into where `edi` points to, incrementing or decrementing `edi` (depending on the direction flag) by 4 bytes each time. Normally, this is used for a `memset`-type operation.

Usually, that instruction is simply written `rep stosd`. Experienced assembly coders know all the details mentioned above just by seeing that. :-)

---

ETA for completeness (thanks PhiS): Each iteration, `ecx` is decremented by 1, and the loop stops when it reaches zero. For `stos`, the only thing you will observe is that `ecx` is cleared at the end. But, for `scas` or the like, where the `repz`/`repnz` prefixes are used, `ecx` can be greater than zero if the operation stopped before exhausting `ecx` bytes/words/whatevers.

Before you ask, `scas` is used for implementing `strchr`-type operations. :-P

Comment: Can you give an example what it does?

Comment: @COMer - It's already in the anwser: like memset - it fills a specified (ecx) amount of memory (at [edi]) with a given value (in eax).

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young - for completeness' sake, I'd suggest you mention that it will also decrement ecx by one each iteration until ecx reaches 0.

Comment: How to know whether it's ecx or other kinds of repetitions ?

Comment: @COMer: It always uses register 1 (`cx`/`ecx`/`rcx`). In your case, since you're using the 32-bit instruction, it will use the 32-bit version of that register, thus, `ecx`.

Comment: @PhiS: I added something, though I don't know if it's comprehensive enough. :-P

Comment: To clarify, is rep stosd similar to:
`memset(edi, eax, ecx)` , where `edi`, `eax`, and `ecx` are the registers?...Except the 2nd parameter may be more than a single byte.

Comment: @SW_user2953243 It's like a 32-bit version of `memset`, where the thing to set to is a 32-bit quantity (unlike `memset`, where the thing to set is a `char`). `ecx` specifies the number of dwords (and not number of bytes) to set.

Comment: @SW_user2953243 More like `memset(edi, eax, ecx * 4)`

Comment: @ColeJohnson Close, except that with `stosd`, the individual bytes in the dword can have different contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
Empty array: 
char buff[256] = { }; 

 776      1c5:   48 8d 95 e0 fc ff ff    lea    -0x320(%rbp),%rdx
 777      1cc:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 778      1d1:   b9 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%ecx
 779      1d6:   48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
 780      1d9:   f3 48 ab                **rep stos %rax,%es:(%rdi)**
```

Comment: That's `rep stosq`, but sure close enough.  (disassembled with AT&T syntax). 
 That looks like un-optimized gcc output; it will inline `rep stos` in some cases instead of calling `memset` even with optimization.  Obviously optimized code wouldn't spend 2 separate instructions getting the pointer into RDI, and would zero RAX with `xor %eax,%eax`.  (If it didn't optimize away the array entirely.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes,   NOT xor %eax,%eax  , is :  xorq %rax, %rax

Comment: Writing EAX zero-extends into RAX, like GCC is doing here with `mov $0, %eax` to zero RAX without the xor-zero peephole optimization (which gcc only looks for at `-O2`, which enables `-fpeephole2`).  Using an extra REX prefix would be strictly worse with XOR, like it would be with MOV. 
 [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)

Comment: Could you clarify your answer, e.g. by adding an explanation? It is not clear how that addresses the question ("What does `rep stos` do?").