# Assembly How to convert REP STOS to C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, machine-code, code-translation

I been debugging `REP STOS DWORD PTR ES:[EDI]` for a while now

From my conclusion it always uses

`ECX` as counter.
`EAX` as the value that will be copied over `EDI` and then appended `ECX` times 
so after putting in the pointed dump of `EDI`

it seems to overwrite the pointed data at EDI with what's
it seems it always only uses ECX as a counter, while changing EDI by 4 bytes.
it stops working when counter hits 0

So I came up with this kind of code

```
while(regs.d.ecx != 0)
{
    *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.edi) = regs.d.eax;
    regs.d.edi += 4;
    regs.d.ecx--;
}
```

Seems to work.. but i'm concerned since I just did this by luck and guess work. Is it solid? like will it always be `ECX` as counter, `EAX` as data, and it always copies 4 bytes never less?

Comment: found a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818856/what-does-this-assembly-do a bit to late.. seems everything is valid.

Comment: I recommend that you get AMD's programmer's manuals (vol 1 for intro, vol 3 for general-purpose instructions) as well as Intel's. Somehow I like better how the AMD's are structured and their tables. Intel's appear a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are almost correct.  The only difference is that the direction flag (`DF`) controls whether 4 is added or subtracted from `EDI` (and it actually is offset from the `ES` segment base, but you probably don't care about that):

```
for (; regs.d.ecx != 0; regs.d.ecx--)
{
    *(unsigned int *)(regs.d.edi) = regs.d.eax;
    regs.d.edi += regs.eflags.df ? -4 : 4;
}
```

Note that the `for (; regs.d.ecx != 0; regs.d.ecx--) { }` is the action of the `REP` prefix, and the body of the loop is the action of `STOS DWORD...`.

Since you are asking a lot of these questions, I think you will find the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volumes 2A and 2B](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-2b-instruction-set-a-z-manual.html) to be useful.  These contain descriptions of each instruction and prefix, including pseudo-code descriptions.

Comment: There's more than DF. Depending on the CPU mode, STOSD may or may not need the operand size prefix (66h), which controls the element size (16 bits vs 32 bits, also AX vs EAX), the address size prefix (67h), which controls how many bits of EDI and ECX are used (16 vs 32). And, finally, it uses the ES segment register, meaning that the virtual address is ES.base + (E)DI. Oh, and it, of course, may cause an exception if the memory can't be written (read-only or not mapped or the privileges (CPL & RPL) aren't sufficient for the segment or underlying pages if page translation is enabled). :)

Comment: blah i don't even understand how flags get generated from this.. well my emulator doesn't even have flags.. and so far so good!. :P, Hoping that stack + registers should be enough

Comment: @SSpoke: `EFLAGS` can be modelled as another register, some of whose bits are set by other instructions.  For the `DF` flag there are specific instructions - `STD` sets it, and `CLD` clears it.