# Undefined behaviour accessing const ptr sometimes

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, undefined-behavior, dereference

I have a header file defined as

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template<int size>
struct B
{
    double arr[size * size];

    constexpr B() : arr()
    {
        arr[0] = 1.;
    }
};

template<int size>
struct A
{
    const double* arr = B<size>().arr;

    void print()
    {
        // including this statement also causes undefined behaviour on subsequent lines
        //printf("%i\n", arr);

        printf("%f\n", arr[0]);
        printf("%f\n", arr[0]); // ???

        // prevent optimisation
        for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
            printf("%f ", arr[i]);
    }
};
```

and call it with

```cpp
auto a = A<8>();
a.print();
```

Now this code only runs expectedly when compiled with **msvc release mode** (all compiled with c++17).

expected output:

```
1.000000
1.000000
```

msvc debug:

```
1.000000
-92559631349317830736831783200707727132248687965119994463780864.000000
```

gcc via mingw (with and without `-g`):

```
1.000000
0.000000
```

However, this behaviour is inconsistent. The expected output is given if I replace `double arr[size * size]` with `double arr[size]` instead. No more problems if I allocate `arr` on the heap of course.

I looked at the assembly of the msvc debug build but I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Why does this undefined behaviour only occur sometimes?

[asm output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJBkc.png)

[decompiled msvc release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxYSn.png)

Comment: `const double* arr = B<size>().arr;` creates dangling pointer.

Comment: "_Why does this undefined behaviour only occur sometimes?_": It is always UB, but causing problems only sometimes lies in the nature of UB.

Comment: I'm aware that it should create a dangling pointer due to stack allocation. But with a smaller array, `double arr[size]`, consistently provides the "expected" output no matter how it's compiled. I was wondering why this behaviour differed depending on the allocation size.

Comment: *I was wondering why this behaviour differed depending on the allocation size.* If the array is stored on the stack, the next call to printf will likely reuse some of that space.

Comment: **Undefined behavior**:  if you're lucky, the program will crash.  If you're unlucky, the program will work as you expected.  Appears you got unlucky on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was completely coincidental that smaller allocations were always addressed in a spot that would not get erased by the `rep stosd` instruction present in printf. Not caused by strange compiler optimisations as I first thought it was.

[What does the "rep stos" x86 assembly instruction sequence do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818856/what-does-the-rep-stos-x86-assembly-instruction-sequence-do)

I also have no idea why I decided to do it this way. Not exactly the question I asked but I ultimately wanted a compile time lookup table so the real solution was `static inline constexpr auto arr = B<size>()` on c++20. Which is why the code looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
const double* arr = B<size>().arr;
```

there is declared a pointer to (the first element of ) a temporary array that will not be alive after the declaration

So dereferencing the pointer results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote:

```
const double* arr = B<size>().arr;
```

The above statement **initializes** a *pointer to `const double`* i.e., `const double*` named `arr` with a **temporary** array object. Since this temporary array object will be destroyed at the end of the **full-expression**, using `arr` will lead to **undefined behavior**.

> Why does this undefined behaviour only occur sometimes?

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>