# Need help understanding Assembly interaction with stack

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

Okay, so here's the deal. To my understanding you can do something like such with the stack in assembly:

```
push 5
push 6
```

Okay so now we have on the stack:  6
                                   5

so

```
pop eax
```

would put 6 into eax correct? However, what if we wished to grab 5 or some value pushed onto the stack before 6 or 5. How would we grab it? (without popping top values off)

I looked at this : [How does the stack work in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556714/how-does-the-stack-work-in-assembly-language)
And it seems that you cannot access things based on address in the stack in assembly. However that doesn't seem to make much sense to me. Or is there a way to iterate through the stack without "popping" things off the top. Thanks, sorry for the "silly" question!

Comment: Not really assembly specific.  Might want to make the question more general to get a better group of responses.  A stack is one of the basic structures from computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack is a memory location just like any other. The ESP register points to the current top of the stack (the stack grows downward in memory, so a `push` instruction will *decrease* the ESP register).

You can access specific values on the stack by indexing from a register:

```
mov ebp,esp
mov eax,[ebp+4]
```

(If I remember correctly, you can't use offset addressing modes with ESP directly, but you can with EBP.)

Answer (score 0):

The stack pointer (which is manipulated by `push` and `pop`) is just a register; `esp`.  You can offset that register to access things relative to the current top of the stack.