# when to create objects in heap vs stack?

Tags: c++, stdmap

Have a look at this piece of code:

```
class Profiler{
    const std::string id;
public:
    Profiler(const std::string id);
    Profiler(const Profiler &t);
//...
}
```

then somewhere in the code:

```
std::map<const std::string, Profiler> profilers;
```

and somewhere else I populate the container as:

```
profilers.insert(std::pair<const std::string, Profiler>(id, Profiler(id)));
```

The above line just invoked `constructor` and `copy constructor` **3 times** in total. one for creating the temporary `Profiler`, one for creating a `pair` and one for `insert` right?
`profilers[id] = Profiler(id);` also has same number of invocations.

1. is there any way to reduce this number?
2. isn't it cheaper(in any terms) to change the signatures properly
   to create a `Profiler` in the heap and store its address in the
   `map` ? (`Profiler` objects are small)

thanks

Comment: Better use a `std::set` with custom comparator instead.

Comment: the `std::map` will store its actual data from the free-store (heap) by default. Only a small handle will occupy the stack.

Comment: If you have C++11 you can use `profilers.emplace()` to reduce copying.

Comment: Keep in mind that stack operations and data copying are typically much cheaper than heap allocations, so it may well be faster to do extra copy-constructors, etc:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264969/why-memory-allocation-on-heap-is-much-slower-than-on-stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my situation, like in my other situation, `stack` is more preferrable.
Why?
better read them one:

1. [why memory allocation on heap is much slower than onstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264969/why-memory-allocation-on-heap-is-much-slower-than-on-stack)
2. [which is faster stack allocation or heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/c-which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation)