# Integer vs Boolean array Swift Performance

Tags: arrays, swift, int, boolean

I tried executing Sieve Of Eratosthenes algorithm using a large Integer array and a large Bool array.

The integer version seems to execute MUCH faster than the boolean one. What is the possible reason for this?

```
import Foundation

var n : Int = 100000000;

var prime = [Bool](repeating: true, count: n+1)
var p = 2
let start = DispatchTime.now()
while((p*p)<=n)
{
    if(prime[p] == true)
    {
        var i = p*2
        while (i<=n)
        {
            prime[i] = false
            i = i + p
        }
    }
    p = p+1
}
let stop = DispatchTime.now()    
let time = (Double)(stop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1000000.0

print("Time = \(time) ms")
```

Boolean array execution time : 78223.342295 ms

```
import Foundation

var n : Int = 100000000;

var prime = [Int](repeating: 1, count: n+1)
var p = 2
let start = DispatchTime.now()
while((p*p)<=n)
{
    if(prime[p] == 1)
    {
        var i = p*2
        while (i<=n)
        {
            prime[i] = 0
            i = i + p
        }
    }
    p = p+1
}
let stop = DispatchTime.now()

let time = (Double)(stop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1000000.0

print("Time = \(time) ms")
```

Integer array execution time : 8535.54546 ms

Comment: This not relevant, perhaps, but you should never say `if prime[p] == true`. If `prime[p]` is a Bool, it _is_ a condition: `if prime[p]`.

Comment: "What is the possible reason for this?" Why not ask Instruments to tell you where the time is being spent? No need to guess (or ask us to do it for you).

Comment: Please post both versions.

Comment: @shallowThought I have done as you asked.

Comment: Did you compile *both* versions in Release mode (with optimizations)? On my iMac  it is approx 950 ms (Bool version) vs 1600 ms (Int version)

Comment: @MartinR With optimizations the Bool version does perform faster. But why is it not the same case without optimizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL, DR:

- Do not attempt to optimize your code in a Debug build. Always run it through the Profiler. `Int` was faster then `Bool` in Debug but the oposite was true when run through the Profiler.
- Heap allocation is expensive. Use your memory judiciously. ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264969/why-is-memory-allocation-on-heap-much-slower-than-on-stack) discusses the complications in C, but also applicable to Swift)

---

#### Long answer

First, let's refactor your code for easier execution:

```
func useBoolArray(n: Int) {
    var prime = [Bool](repeating: true, count: n+1)
    var p = 2

    while((p*p)<=n)
    {
        if(prime[p] == true)
        {
            var i = p*2
            while (i<=n)
            {
                prime[i] = false
                i = i + p
            }
        }
        p = p+1
    }
}

func useIntArray(n: Int) {
    var prime = [Int](repeating: 1, count: n+1)
    var p = 2

    while((p*p)<=n)
    {
        if(prime[p] == 1)
        {
            var i = p*2
            while (i<=n)
            {
                prime[i] = 0
                i = i + p
            }
        }
        p = p+1
    }
}
```

Now, run it in the Debug build:

```
let count = 100_000_000
let start = DispatchTime.now()

useBoolArray(n: count)
let boolStop = DispatchTime.now()

useIntArray(n: count)
let intStop = DispatchTime.now()

print("Bool array:", Double(boolStop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
print("Int array:", Double(intStop.uptimeNanoseconds - boolStop.uptimeNanoseconds) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))

// Bool array: 70.097249517
// Int array: 8.439799614
```

So `Bool` is a lot **slower** than `Int` right? Let's run it through the Profiler by pressing `Cmd + I` and choose the Time Profile template. (Somehow the Profiler wasn't able to separate these functions, probably because they were inlined so I had to run only 1 function per attempt):

```
let count = 100_000_000
useBoolArray(n: count)
// useIntArray(n: count)

// Bool: 1.15ms
// Int: 2.36ms
```

Not only they are an order of magnitude faster than Debug but the results are reversed to: `Bool` is now **faster** than `Int`!!! The Profiler doesn't tell us why how so we must go on a witch hunt. Let's check the memory allocation by adding an Allocation instrument:

[image: Bool Array]
[image: int Array]

Ha! Now the differences are laid bare. The `Bool` array uses only one-eight as much memory as `Int` array. Swift array uses the same internals as `NSArray` so it's allocated on the heap and [heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264969/why-is-memory-allocation-on-heap-much-slower-than-on-stack) is slow.

When you think even more about it: a `Bool` value only take up 1 bit, an `Int` takes 64 bits on a 64-bit machine. Swift may have chosen to represent a `Bool` with a single byte, while an `Int` takes 8 bytes, hence the memory ratio. In Debug, this difference may have caused all the difference as the runtime must do all kinds of checks to ensure that it's actually dealing with a `Bool` value so the `Bool` array method takes significantly longer.

Moral of the lesson: don't optimize your code in Debug mode. It can be misleading!

Answer (score 1):

*(A partial answer ...)*

As @MartinR mentions in his comments to the question, there is no such major difference between the two cases if you build for release mode (with optimizations); the `Bool` case is slightly faster due its smaller memory footprint (but equally fast as e.g. `UInt8` which has the same footprint).

Running instruments to profile the (non-optimized) debug build, we clearly see that the array element access & assignment is the culprit for the `Bool` case (an as far as my brief testing has seen; for all types except the integer ones, `Int`, `UInt16`, and so on).

[image]

[image]

We can further ascertain that its not the writing part in particular that yields the overhead, but rather the repeated *accessing* of the `i:th` element.

[image]

The same explicit read-access tests for an array of integer elements show no such large overhead.

It would almost seem as if the random element access is, for some reason, not working as it should (for non-integer types) when compiling with debug build config.