# Stack Allocation vs Heap Allocation

Tags: c++, performance, heap-memory, stack-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Which is faster: Stack allocation or Heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/c-which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation)

I was testing the following code with and without TEST being defined:

```
#include <cstdlib> // atoi

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) {
    int times = 100000000;

    switch ( argc ) {
        case 2:
          times = atoi( argv[1] );
    } // switch

    volatile int *arr = 0;
    delete arr;

    for ( int i = 0; i < times; i += 1 ) {
    #ifdef TEST
        arr = new int[10];
        arr[0] = 5;
        delete [ ] arr;
    #else
        volatile int arr[10];
        arr[0] = 5;
    #endif
    }
}
```

The following is my time output:

```
$ time ./q1test    // variable TEST defined  
real   0m7.319s  
user   0m7.289s  
sys    0m0.007s  

$ time ./q1notest  // variable TEST not defined  
real   0m0.281s  
user   0m0.276s  
sys    0m0.003s  

$ time ./q1dynopt  // variable TEST defined with compiler optimization
real   0m7.137s  
user   0m7.116s  
sys    0m0.006s  

$ time ./q1nodynopt // variable TEST not defined with compiler optimization
real   0m0.053s  
user   0m0.048s  
sys    0m0.003s
```

I would like to know why there the first case is so much slower than the second?
Also, why doesn't compiler optimization affect the first case?

I know its due to stack allocation vs heap allocation, but I would like to understand it in more depth if possible.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of manually memory management.

Comment: You should note that the first case is optimized almost as much as the second case (i.e. 182ms vs. 228ms). The additional 7 seconds is taken up by calling the memory allocator/deallocator 100,000,000 times. At 70ns per `new`/`delete` pair, it's not exactly "slow".