# Copying to binary file row of a matrix

Tags: c++

I want to write each row of a matrix to a binary file.
I try writing it like this:

```
vector< vector<uint32_t> > matrix;
```

...

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
ofile->write( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&matrix[i]), sizeof(uint32_t*sizeof(matrix[i])) );
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < numcols; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << left << setw(10) << matrix[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

but it doesn't work, I get garbage numbers.

Any help appreciated,

Ted.

Comment: Are you sure you need a binary format. Its usually not worth the hassle.

Comment: Usually... But when it is, it is worth by a LOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case interjay's guidelines weren't enough:

```
vector< vector<uint32_t> > matrix;

for(size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i) 
  ofile.write( (char*)&matrix[i][0], sizeof(matrix[i][0])*matrix[i].size() );
```

Out-of-context question: Why is `ofile` a pointer? (certainly don't need to be in this example)

Comment: Well ofile is a pointer in my program. is that bad (perofrmance-wise)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/c-which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation

Answer (score 5):

Some issues:

1. `&matrix[i]` will give you a pointer to a `vector<uint32_t>` object. If you want a pointer to that vector's contained data, use `&matrix[i][0]`.
2. `sizeof(matrix[i])` is the size of the vector object itself, not its contents. Use `matrix[i].size()` to get the number of elements.
3. Instead of `sizeof(uint32_t * x)`, use `sizeof(uint32_t) * x`.
4. The second `for` loop isn't actually nested in the first `for` loop. You need to rearrange your braces.