# View stack pointer in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, stack

I have attempted a partial answer to this question:

[CPU cost order of magnitude for some basic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977726/cpu-cost-order-of-magnitude-for-some-basic-operations/4977886#4977886)

just because it was an interesting exercise whilst I am learning to use Xcode.

My answer would hold a little more water if I could identify the stack pointer in Xcode when targetting iOS. I know how to find my way to the registers, but I don't know which one is SP.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just earned the tumbleweed badge for this!

I have now discovered the answer. It's usually r13 in ARM processors, and is labelled $sp in the Xcode debugger. Obvious really, when you actually look for it!