# How to do proper initialization and allocation of the composite struct?

Tags: c

I need to create and implement usage of the struct that contains an array inside it. How to do proper initialization and allocation of the struct and array? Here's my current implementation that seems to work. However, not sure is it proper way and where is the struct allocated (on stack or on heap memory). IMHO a call to malloc makes to store an array on heap, however not sure about remaining struct members. Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct {

  uint8_t objectSize;
  double objectDepth; 

} ObjectData;

typedef struct {

  ObjectData *objectList;
  double startMark;
  double endMark;

} MyDataPacket;
```

Here is the function that fills and returns the struct:

```
void getMyPacket(MyDataPacket *myDataPacket, uint8_t objectNum)
{
  myDataPacket->startMark = 10.0; 
  myDataPacket->endMark = 60.0; 
  myDataPacket->objectList = malloc(objectNum * sizeof(MyDataPacket));

  uint8_t x;
  for (x = 0; x < objectNum; x++)
  { 
    myDataPacket->objectList[x].objectSize = x; // just test values
    myDataPacket->objectList[x].objectDepth = x; // just test values
  }
}
```

Here's function calling part:

```
uint8_t objectNum = 10;
MyDataPacket myDataPacket;
getMyPacket(&myDataPacket, objectNum);
```

Does the struct data is mixed and placed both on stack and heap, or everything resides at one place?

Comment: Shouldn't you allocate the size of `ObjectData` in the `getMyPacket` function for `objectList`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I thinka that's pretty much the answer.

Comment: I did allocation with malloc - "myDataPacket->objectList = malloc(objectNum * sizeof(MyDataPacket));"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `myDataPacket` is allocated on the heap, then it will all be on the heap:

```
MyDataPacket *myDataPacket = malloc(sizeof(MyDataPacket));
```

If `myDataPacket` is an automatic variable, it will *all* live on the stack, including the `objectList` pointer itself, the memory *it points to* however, will be on the heap:

```
MyDataPacket myDataPacket; //this is all on the stack
myDataPacket->objectList = malloc(...) //memory allocated here is on the heap
```

If it's a global variable, it depends on whether or not it's initialized, and whether it's initialized to `zero` or not, but *generally speaking* uninitialized variables go to the `.bss` section and initialized variables go to the `data` section, and of course the dynamically allocated memory will be on the heap as usual.

If you're worried about efficiency check this SO question:

[Which is faster: Stack allocation or Heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/c-which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation)

Comment: Is it good practice to have mixed places, for example like my code?

Comment: @Centurion sometimes it's unavoidable, if you're worried about efficiency check the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: If `myDataPacket` is a local variable inside a function, then it will be placed on the stack, while `myDataPacket.objectList` will be placed on the heap (and also needs to be free'd).

Comment: So, the struct is just a set of "variables-members" that might be placed on separate places. Just heard that structs are always placed on stack. It seems that it depends on how members are initialized and might have different places.

Comment: @Centurion That's correct. If `myDataPacket` was a global variable instead of a local, then it would be stored in yet another segment of memory. And if you had it as a pointer and allocated it with `malloc` then it would be on the heap too, but most likely disjoint from the memory allocated for `objectList`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
myDataPacket->objectList = malloc(objectNum * sizeof(MyDataPacket));
```

to

```
myDataPacket->objectList = malloc(objectNum * sizeof(ObjectData));
```

That should fix your problem. You are currently allocating a number of MyDataPackets instead of ObjectData's.

Comment: Yep, that's a mistake :) Thanks.