# Store an int in a char* [C]

Tags: c, printf

```
int main()
{
   int n = 56;
   char buf[10]; //want char* buf instead
   sprintf(buf, "%i", n);
   printf("%s\n", buf);

   return 0;
}
```

This piece of code works, my question is what if i want the same behaviour, with buf being a char* ?

Comment: When you do `char buf[10]` memory allocate statically you not need to de-allocate, But for `cher* buff` you have to do memory management explicitly. [Here is difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836509/character-string-pointer-vs-array/13836587#13836587) between two declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buf` is an array statically allocated on the stack. For it to be of type `char *` you need to allocate dynamically the memory. I guess what you want is something like this:

```
int main()
{
   int n = 56;
   char * buf = NULL;
   buf = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
   sprintf(buf, "%i", n);
   printf("%s\n", buf);

   // don't forget to free the allocated memory
   free(buf);

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out by 'Thomas Padron-McCarthy' in the comments, you should not cast the return of `malloc()`. You will find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). You could also remove completely the `sizeof(char)` as it will always by `1`.

Comment: Thank You, I'm still pretty unconfortable with the manual memory management.

Comment: No problem, I added the code to release the memory if you really are not used to this! @schnaader yeah I thought so too now that he says he is new to the concept

Comment: No, buf isn't already a char*. An array is an array and a pointer is a pointer!

Comment: Hmmm Do you have a link to understand what you mean by that? I've read something similar the other day on another SO question but can't grasp why buf would not be considered of type `char *` even if it references a static array on the stack here.

Comment: buf is _not_ "referencing" a static array, it _is_ a static array. It is not a pointer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c/1641963#1641963

Comment: Ok, I've never heard of the concept of array which are converted to pointers implicitely when needed so thanks for pointing this out

Comment: As a wise man said: Don't cast malloc, and sizeof(char) is always 1

Comment: Why not cast malloc() ? I thought it was mandatory to cast the return of a malloc() call? And yes sizeof(char) is always 1 but what is the point of putting 1 hardcoded in the call when you can just be consistent and always use sizeof() of the expected type? I think it would be a mistake to remove the sizeof() in this case and more confusing than useful

Comment: Both of those are "signals" that many C programmers will interpret as signs of an inexperienced programmer, whose code will have to be treated with suspicion. About the cast, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Thanks for your link again, I'll have to dig up the emails I had in my previous company about why I must cast my calls and understand where I missed something (I did not cast at first but I guess wasn't sure of what I was doing). I still disagree on the point of `sizeof(char)`. I do not see why adding this would mean I'm an inexperienced programmer. It just seems easier to use the same call convention of malloc() everywhere instead of specific cases where I know the size of the type anyway. Same for someone reading my code or changing it later.

Comment: It is not that it is a specific case where you happen to know the size of the type, but that sizes in C are measured in char, so by definition sizeof(char) is 1. But yes, there are also arguments _for_ using sizeof(char).

Comment: The more I answer here, the more I learn. Thanks a lot for pointing all this out and improving my understanding of C.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference when writing

```
char* buf;
```

is that it is uninitialized and no memory is allocated, so you'll have to take care yourself:

```
char* buf = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
// ... more code here
free(buf); // don't forget this or you'll get a memory leak
```

This is called [dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (as opposed to static allocation) and it allows you nice things like [changing the amount of allocated memory at runtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) using `realloc` or using a variable in the `malloc` call.
Also note that memory allocation can fail if the amount of memory is too large, in this case the returned pointer will be `NULL`.

Technically, `sizeof(char)` above isn't needed because 1 `char` will always be 1 byte in size, but most other data types are bigger and the multiplication is important - `malloc(100)` allocates 100 bytes, `malloc(100 * sizeof(int))` allocates the amount of memory needed for 100 `int`s which usually is 400 bytes on 32-bit systems, but can vary.

```
int amount = calculate_my_memory_needs_function();
int* buf = malloc(amount * sizeof(int));
if (buf == NULL) {
  // oops!
}
// ...
if (more_memory_needed_suddenly) {
   amount *= 2; // we just double it
   buf = realloc(buf, amount * sizeof(int));
   if (!buf) { // Another way to check for NULL
     // oops again!
   }
}
// ...
free(buf);
```

Another useful function is `calloc` that takes two parameters (first: number of elements to allocate, second: size of an element in bytes) and initializes the memory to 0.

Comment: No, buf isn't already of type char*. An array is an array and a pointer is a pointer!

Comment: Don't cast malloc, and sizeof(char) is always 1

Comment: Edited the cast, will write something about `sizeof(char)`, but keep it for educational purposes - better write an unneeded `sizeof(char)` than forget a needed `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think calloc (or malloc if you don't have calloc) is what you're after.