# Reading a .bmp image with fread()

Tags: c, fread

I am trying to read a .bmp image and write the data into a text file. Code is running fine but the problem is, it cannot read whole image once so I have to call `fread()` function many times. While doing this my code is repeatedly storing the first read data into the text file. What changes do I have to do in order to read the whole image properly? Below is my code snippet.

```
int size = width * height;
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size]; 
filename = "image.bmp";
fname = "image_data.txt";
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "w");

while(totalBytes < size)
{
    readsize = fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f);
    totalBytes += readsize;
    for(i = 0; i < readsize; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d", data[i]);
        if((i % width) == 0 && i != 0)
            fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fseek(f, readsize, SEEK_SET);
    readsize = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `fseek` call is wrong. After the `fread` call the file position will be behind the read data, so you can just read on without seeking.

What happened before was that you read X bytes, did an unnecessary but harmless `fseek` to file position X, then read Y bytes, but did a harmful `fseek` back to file position X, so you kept reading the same data again.

```
while(totalBytes < size)
{
    readsize=fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f);
    totalBytes+=readsize;
    for(i = 0; i < readsize; i++)
        {
          fprintf(fp,"%d",data[i]);
              if((i % width)== 0 && i!=0)
               fprintf(fp,"\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: ` Also note that sizeof(unsigned char) will always be 1` -- if you can assume that the code is not running on, for example, many 16 bit DSP processors. A safe assumption, sure, but not so safe to warrant being brought up.

Comment: OK, removed it. Getting a bit tired of those holy C wars ("sizeof(char) is 1", "don't cast malloc"...) here - just yesterday I used "sizeof(char)" and got a comment not to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895073/store-an-int-in-a-char-c/13895113#13895113

Comment: I understand about the "don't cast malloc" holy war frustration, but the bottom line is a char is not guaranteed to be 8 bits wide. Even beyond that though, replacing the sizeof with a const is not a great idea for code maintainability purposes; if anything, I would suggest in this case to use `sizeof(*data)` so that if `data`s type changes in the future, the size intention is still met. Anyway, I +1'd your answer; I was getting ready to post about the fseek when your answer came up.

Comment: @schnaader I used this code here https://pastebin.com/0y2ayrJ9 and all I get in console is 6969696969Read failed