# C++ Difference between *new and new

Tags: c++, object, pointers

This question may be a duplicate. I have been looking online everywhere to figure this out, but I can't find anything. What is the difference between 'new' and '*new'?:

```
int main()
{
    class Cat
    {
        //Code
    }

    new Cat();
    *new Cat();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, where did you see this?

Comment: @AlokSave no its not a duplicate of that. im still learning c++ and i dont even know what a memory leak is

Comment: @JBentley Im from java. I just want to be able to put new objects in an array/list. In java you do "object[5] = new object();"

Comment: @Harry I meant did you see an example of `*new` in some code you saw somewhere?

Comment: @JBentley nope. I mean I havent seen this in c++ i have only seen it in java. im trying to figure out how to make a new object and store it in the memory like you do in java.

Comment: @harry I see. Well you should look into the [difference between stack and heap memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408670/stack-static-and-heap-in-c) and the [performance considerations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/c-which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation) of each. You shouldn't just place all your objects on the heap (which is what `new` does) by default. Also, even when you do want heap memory, avoid `new` and use smart pointers instead, as they take care of the memory management for you.

Answer (score 17):

These are not two separate things. There's not a `new` and a `*new`. The second is simply applying unary `*` to the result of `new Cat()`.

`new Cat()` is a *new-expression*. It dynamically allocates and initialises a `Cat` object and evaluates to a pointer to that object. If you then apply unary `*` to that pointer, you dereference it to get the `Cat` object.

There is not very often a good reason to apply unary `*` immediately to a *new-expression*. The reason is because you're immediately following the pointer and haven't stored the pointer anywhere. Consider if you had done this:

```
Cat c = *new Cat();
```

This would result in a memory leak that you can't recover from. A `Cat` object is dynamically allocated and then copied into `c`. The dynamically allocated `Cat` now lingers around and you don't have a pointer to it through which you can `delete` the object. This is very bad.

```
Cat& c = *new Cat();
```

This is a little better, because at least now `c` is just a reference to the dynamically allocated object. You can always do `delete &c;` to destroy the object. However, it masks the fact that `Cat` was dynamically allocated. If I were reading this code, I wouldn't expect `c` to be referring to a dynamically allocated object.

You must remember to destroy dynamically allocated objects. Dereferencing the result of a *new-expression* makes that more difficult to achieve, so avoid it.

Answer (score 12):

This expression:

```
new Cat();
```

Creates dynamically an object of type `Cat`, and you are ignoring the returned pointer (not storing it, not dereferencing, nothing). This expression:

```
*new Cat();
```

Does the same as the one above, except that you are also dereferencing the pointer returned by `new`. But dereferencing a pointer *per se* is an operation has no side-effect.

Concretely, therefore, the effect of both expressions is the same. The important bit is that **you are leaking memory twice** by losing the one and only reference to the objects you create dynamically.

Keep in mind that every object created with `new` must be destroyed by a corresponding call to `delete`. For instance, if you stored the returned pointer this way:

```
Cat* pCat = new Cat();
```

That would allow you to do, later on:

```
delete pCat;
```

And avoid memory leaks. Also, this:

```
Cat& cat = *new Cat();
```

Would allow you to do, later on:

```
delete &cat;
```

And avoid memory leaks again. Notice, however, that this would not be an option:

```
Cat cat = *new Cat();
```

The above would still give you a memory leak. The reason is that it would **copy** the object obtained by dereferencing the pointer returned by `new` into `cat`. In other words, `cat` would be a different object than (although identical to) the one the `new` expression created.

The object created by the `new` expression, on the other hand, would be lost - resulting in a memory leak again.

In Modern C++, it is advisable to avoid manual memory management by calling `new` and `delete`; rather, consider using smart pointers (which one depends on the ownership policy that you need). For instance:

```
#include <memory>

// ...

std::shared_ptr<Cat> pCat = std::make_shared<Cat>();
```

Smart pointers take care of automatically destroying the referenced object when the last smart pointer to the pointed object is destroyed.

Comment: How do you know he's leaking memory?  I use the first form fairly often without leaking memory, at least in specific types of applications.  It all depends on what the constructor of `Cat` does.  Given that in many applications, the object will be deleted by a `delete this;` in the object, in reaction to some external event, there doesn't seem to be any reason to do anything with the returned value of the operator new.  (The constructor has, of course, taken care of an registration for the needed events.)  This seems to be the most usual case when `new` is used.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It took me a while to understand what you meant, mostly because you seem to be making a lot of non-assumptions about the OP's question. It seems reasonable IMO to assume from the text that there is nothing like that going on here. There is a regular class in a complete program, and the OP is asking about the difference between `new` and `*new`, so I find it very unlikely that they might have figured out some self-registration, self-deletion, and event-listening pattern in there.

Comment: You seem to be making the assumptions.  The self-registration/self-deletion pattern is extremely frequent, and should probably be assumed in the lack of additional information.  At any rate, just assigning a value you get from `new` to a smart pointer, without any additional information, is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Btw, why are you picking on my answer in particular? Everybody here is mentioning memory leaks - and that because it's reasonable to assume that what we see is what the OP has. A simple program with a simple local class that does no event-registering and no self-deletion.

Comment: Because I saw it first.  The issues are not as evident as most of the responders seem to think.  (But the `*new` version is almost certainly an error.  Unless he does something with the reference.)

Answer (score 6):

Does it help you:

```
Cat *ptr = new Cat();
Cat cat = *new Cat(); /* memory leak :( */
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not using variables though.

Comment: Note that the latter copies the new `Cat` into `cat`, then leaks the memory allocated with `new`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks, I mentioned it in the answer

Comment: Of course, if you're allocating the class dynamically, it probably shouldn't support copy, so the second version shouldn't compile.

Comment: @JamesKanze there is always a default `=` operator and copy constructor in c++ which are implemented, so it works but probably won't work as expected.

Comment: @0x90 There is _not_ a default = operator if I declare one (private, and without an implementation).  There is _not_ a default + operator if the class inherits from `boost::noncopiable`.  Both are widespread and well known techniques for inhibiting assignment, and in actual practice, most classes you would actually allocate dynmically will use one of them.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are right but it is almost as to say there is no war when there is total peace.