# Time complexity of declaring an array in C++

Tags: c++, time-complexity

What's the time complexity of the following code in C++: (note that I'm using gcc, so len is taken as an input from the user)

`int array[len]; \\array is uninitialized`

Is it O(1) or O(len) ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking about the VLA extension that GCC provides?

Comment: This might be better posed as `new int[len]`. I'm pretty certain that automatic variable allocation will be O(1), dynamic might have a O(log(len)) feel to it if the OS needs to start thinking harder about paging &c.

Comment: @UnholySheep I have no idea (I am new to c++). I just simply use codeblocks with mingw and I can create an dynamic array.

Comment: I'm fairly sure if you look at the asm; it'll be O(1) ... if you have some more interesting objects though i'll be O(N)

Comment: What is `len` defined as?

Comment: Bonus question: what about `Foo array[len]` where `Foo` is a struct defined by me ?

Comment: @AlexKChen Well that depends on Foo now doesn't it.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yeah, so I mean is it then `O(sizeoff(Foo)*len)` or `O(sizeof(Foo))` or anything else ?

Comment: @AlexKChen who knows - like I said; depends on Foo and what the compiler can optimise away.

Comment: I suspect it is more like O(0)

Comment: This only works for `len` reasonably small, and only as an extension to C++

Comment: Anyway, variable length arrays do not exist in C++, they are only allowed by a gcc extension.

Comment: @4386427 I think the OP is just curious.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation).

Answer (score 5):

In general for POD types the time will be O(1).

If you have user defined constructors (or destructors, I assume that the time taken to release the resources should also be considered) then I would expect the time complexity to be O(n).

If you can wait a little, I submitted an article to [Overload](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/c78/) on the code size and execution time required for objects that are allocated automatically and dynamically. I'm expecting it to be out this April.

Update:
Here is the link for the published Overload article [No news is good news](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2489)

Answer (score 1):

The general rule:

```
type name[size];
```

If your type is Plain Old Data ([POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)) than compiler can invoke allocation and construction in O(1).
 Otherwise en explicit constructor call is required for each entity which is O(n).

Comment: The OP is asking about VLA extension of GCC.