# C#: of two methods which calculate Levenshtein distance, why does the heap-allocated "cost" array outperform the stack-allocated "cost" array?

Tags: c#, optimization, levenshtein-distance, stackalloc

Consider the following C# implementation (not my own) for Levenshtein distance: "Fastenshtein/StaticLevenshtein.cs". I removed the original comments and eliminated some whitespace for brevity. Source - https://github.com/DanHarltey/Fastenshtein/blob/master/src/Fastenshtein/StaticLevenshtein.cs.

```
// Fastenshtein/StaticLevenshtein.cs
public static int Distance(string value1, string value2)
{
  if (value2.Length == 0) { return value1.Length; }

  // *** NOTE: "costs" is heap-allocated. ***
  int[] costs = new int[value2.Length];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < costs.Length;) { costs[i] = ++i; }

  for (int i = 0; i < value1.Length; i++)
  {
    int cost = i;
    int previousCost = i;
    char value1Char = value1[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < value2.Length; j++)
    {
      int currentCost = cost;
      cost = costs[j];

      if (value1Char != value2[j])
      {
        if (previousCost < currentCost) { currentCost = previousCost; }
        if (cost < currentCost) { currentCost = cost; }
        ++currentCost;
      }

      costs[j] = currentCost;
      previousCost = currentCost;
    }
  }

  return costs[costs.Length - 1];
}
```

I noticed that the "costs" array was heap-allocated. I wondered, for use cases dealing strictly with small strings (32 characters or less), if an implementation using a stack-allocated "costs" array would improve performance.

For my stack-allocated "costs" implementation, I simply replaced `int[] costs = new int[value2.Length];` with `Span<int> costs = stackalloc int[value2.Length];`:

```
// Stack-allocated "costs"
public static int Distance_StackAlloc(string value1, string value2)
{
  if (value2.Length == 0) { return value1.Length; }

  // *** NOTE: "costs" is now stack-allocated. ***
  Span<int> costs = stackalloc int[value2.Length];

  // ... remaining code is identical to the original, and 
  // is omitted here for brevity.
}
```

To compare performance, I used BenchmarkDotNet (https://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.html). I loaded 1,000 random words from the following text file into a `string[]`, and measured the time to sum the Levenshtein distance from each to the word "foofaraw" - https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt. Here is the setup code:

```
[Params(1000)] public int N;
[Params("foofaraw")] public string Word;
private string[] _words;

[GlobalSetup]
public void Setup()
{
  // Same seed so each test uses the same data.
  Random rng = new Random(2112340164);
  _words =
    File
    .ReadAllLines("words_alpha.txt") // shortened path
    .OrderBy(_ => rng.Next())
    .Take(N)
    .ToArray();
}
```

And here is the pseudocode for each Benchmark:

```
[Benchmark]
public int Test()
{
  int sum = 0;
  foreach (string word in _words) { sum += Levenshtein(Word, word); }
  return sum;
}
```

Surprisingly, the heap-allocated version seems to outperform the stack-allocated version! Below are the results from BenchmarkDotNet. Some observations:

- The heap-allocated version allocates 63,840 bytes across 1,000 invocations.
- The stack-allocated version has 50% more branch mispredictions.

  N: 1000
  Word: "foofaraw"

| Method | Mean | Mispredictions/Op | Instructions/Op | CacheMisses/Op | Alloc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StaticLevenshtein | 180.3 μs | 10,191 | 361,551 | 978 | 63840 B |
| StackAllocCosts | 199.0 μs | 15,368 | 335,321 | 37 | - |

Can anyone shed some light on the results?

---

Edit: the following question and its answers seem to suggest the behavior that I would *expect* to see. I posted this question because my benchmark results do *not* follow what I would expect. [Which is faster: Stack allocation or Heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation)

---

Edit: Here are the remaining statistics from the BenchmarkDotNet results:

```
| Method            | Mean     | Error   | StdDev  | Median   |
|------------------ |---------:|--------:|--------:|---------:|
| StaticLevenshtein | 180.3 μs | 3.50 μs | 5.45 μs | 177.6 μs |
| StackAllocCosts   | 199.0 μs | 3.24 μs | 4.10 μs | 198.4 μs |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is faster: Stack allocation or Heap allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation)

Comment: I do not think so. Unless I missed something specific, the answers there seem to confirm the behavior I would *expect* to see from my tests. Namely, that I would expect the stack-allocated version would outperform the heap-allocated version. However, in my benchmark results it appears the heap-allocated version is faster for some reason.

Comment: Do you have an error margin value on those?

Comment: Yes! I edited the question to include those other statistics.

Comment: Well, it is perfectly possible that the miss-predictions can explain the performance difference. Branch-predictors are quite complex, and not reusing the same memory might help it make better predictions. And this might have a larger impact than the small allocation overhead. Keep in mind that the numbers might be different when run in a larger application, with a more complex allocation pattern.

Comment: I agree. However, is it surprising that the impact of the branch mispredictions in the stack-allocated version outweighs the impact of the cache misses and allocations of the heap-allocated version (978 vs 37 misses, 63,840 bytes vs 0 bytes)?

Comment: AFAIK, branch prediction on modern x86-64 processor is independent of the target data addresses. The content of items matters for the miss-prediction rate but that's all. The most important factor is the address of the instruction doing the conditional jump. On which CPU architecture do you run this code? It is weird to see a branch miss-prediction change for the same code and same data (content). I guess the JIT generate a less optimal code. Or maybe the code is miss-aligned and there is a JCC erratum issue (only on Intel CPUs).

Comment: Cache misses can be cheap if the memory latency is overlapped with computations. A L1 miss with a L2 hit can be quite cheap. But a L3 miss is so expensive that the CPU can often hardly overlap the latency with computations. It is not clear what "CacheMisses" is supposed to be here : L1/L2/L3 misses?

Comment: Btw, heap allocation can allocated data at the same address so there is no much more cache misses. This is often the case for native language (like C/C++) due to the way standard allocator works. AFAIK, C# use a kind of stack allocation internally in the GC for small arrays so addresses are expected often not to be the same (for small ones). But for big ones, it may be able to recycle allocated memory (possibly not always regarding whether data are often collected or not).